# Como e quando usar o Finally após um Try?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, try-finally

Primeiramente gostaria de saber do porque em utilizar o `finally`

Quais as suas vantagens? Ele realmente só serve pra quando ocorre uma saída de dentro do escopo de um bloco `try-catch`, como quando ocorre algum `return` ou `goto` lá dentro?

Comment: Um comentário apenas a acrescentar as boas respostas que já aqui estão. Existem casos raros em que o finally pode não ser executado, mais propriamente em caso de falhas catastróficas do sistema (power cut, out of memory). Convém manter isso em mente e não presumir que todo o código no finally é garantido. (Num tom mais de brincadeira) Veja o este exemplo (http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/My-Tales.aspx)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Outras respostas já responderam o mais importante sobre a questão. Complementando, o uso mais comum para o `finally` é a limpeza de recursos.

Quando você usa uma declaração de variável com `using` na verdade está usando um `try-finally`

Então quando faz:

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

É o mesmo que:

```
{
  Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
  try {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
  }
  finally {
    if (font1 != null)
      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
  }
}
```

De fato é apenas *syntax sugar*. O compilador realmente troca o `using` pela segunda construção.

O `catch` é usado para capturar exceções e só, o `finally` é executado **sempre** após o final de um bloco de código dentro do `try` ou `catch`, se houver um, havendo exceção ou não. O `finally` será executado de qualquer forma, mesmo que antes dele tenha um `return` ou `goto` tentando evitá-lo. Não é possível sair do bloco de código iniciado pelo `try` sem passar pelo `finally` (pelo menos não em condições normais do C#, como bem lembrando pelo Omni, há situações catastróficas que o CLR pode não garantir a execução do `finally`, além disso, em tese é possível mudar o IL para evitá-lo, mas isso é algo errado para fazer).

Não há como usar um `return` ou `goto` dentro de um `finally`. Ou você usa no `try` ou no `catch` ou o coloca após o `finally`. Lembrando que se estiver depois do bloco `finally`, ele pode não ser executado, como bem demonstra o último código da resposta do Lucas Nunes.

Achei essa [excelente resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421812/221800) (veja também a [resposta do Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421827/221800)) mostrando como funciona o `return` no bloco protegido pelo `try`. Este código:

```
static int Test() {
    try {
        return SomeNumber();
    } finally {
        Foo();
    }
}
```

Compila para o CIL:

```
.method private hidebysig static int32 Test() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 CS$1$0000)
    L_0000: call int32 Program::SomeNumber()
    L_0005: stloc.0 
    L_0006: leave.s L_000e
    L_0008: call void Program::Foo()
    L_000d: endfinally 
    L_000e: ldloc.0 
    L_000f: ret 
    .try L_0000 to L_0008 finally handler L_0008 to L_000e
}
```

Que seria o mesmo que:

```
private static int Test()
{
    int CS$1$0000;
    try
    {
        CS$1$0000 = SomeNumber();
    }
    finally
    {
        Foo();
    }
    return CS$1$0000;
}
```

O `return` é executado no final, mas a expressão contida nele é executado onde estaria o `return` no código original.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/FinallyAlone.cs).

Comment: +1 pela menção às condições não normais de saída.

Answer (score 15):

Você deve utilizar `finally` para finalizar/liberar recursos que você possa ter usado em um `try`, mesmo que um exceção seja lançada, o código no `finally` será executado.

A funcionamento é basicamente esse:

```
try
{
     // seu código
}
catch
{
     // exceção 
}
finally
{
     // sempre faz isso
}
```

**Por exemplo:**
Supondo você abre um arquivo no `try`, mas ocorre exceção. Em `finally` é o local correto para você fechar o arquivo.

```
 String path = @"arquivo_qualquer.dat";
 System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
 char[] buffer = new char[10];

 try
 {
     file.ReadBlock(buffer, index, buffer.Length);
 }
 catch (System.IO.IOException e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Erro de leitura em: {0}. Mensagem = {1}", path, e.Message);
 }
 finally
 {
     if (file != null)
     {
         file.Close();
     }
 }
```

Note que o código acima é diferente de:

```
String path = @"arquivo_qualquer.dat";
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
char[] buffer = new char[10];

try
{
    file.ReadBlock(buffer, index, buffer.Length);
}
catch (System.IO.IOException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Erro de leitura em: {0}. Mensagem = {1}", path, e.Message);
}

if (file != null)
{
    file.Close();
}
```

Nesse segundo caso não há garantia de que `file` será fechado, enquanto  no primeiro há. 
O exemplo abaixo ilustra isso, onde o `return` no `catch` impede que as últimas linhas do programa sejam executadas, mas as do `finally` serão.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "1000";
    Object obj = str;
    int numero = 0;

    try
    {
        // Essa conversão falhará.
        numero = (int)obj;

        Console.WriteLine("Essa linha não será executada.");
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A conversão falhou.");

        // Esse return fará com que o último WriteLine não seja executado.
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Essa linha sempre será executada.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Aparentemente essa linha seria executada.");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

O `finally` só serve para uso juntamente com um `try/catch`.

O uso dele é indicado para situações de um bloco `try` em que, havendo sucesso ou falha, o código sempre será executado. Isto é útil para desalocação de objetos, auditoria em log de alguma informação, ou algum código que seja imprescindível a execução.

Assim como o `catch`, o bloco `finally` é opcional.

Não é necessário usá-lo para retornar algum valor. Pode ser usado, mas não é obrigatório.

Uso:

```
try 
{
    /* Aqui fica o código propenso a algum erro */
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    /* Aqui é executado quando alguma exceção acontece */
} 
finally 
{
    /* Independente de ter caído ou não no catch, este trecho sempre executa */
}
```

Referência: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx

Answer (score 6):

O código dentro de um bloco `finally` será executado independentemente se há ou não uma exceção. Isso é útil quando se trata de certas funções em que você precisa fazer *conexões de fechamento*, *desconectar-se* ou *liberar um objeto*.

```
try
{
    FazerAlgumaCoisa();
}
catch
{
    CapturarAlgo();
}
finally
{
    SempreFazerIsso();
}
```

Você poderia estar fazendo isso:

```
try
{
    FazerAlgumaCoisa();
}
catch
{
    CapturarAlgo();
}

SempreFazerIsso();
```

No último código, a chamada `SempreFazerIsso()` não será executado se o código dentro da instrução `catch` emitir um retorno ou lançar uma nova exceção.

<sub>[**Fonte**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547806/1608936)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

O "finally" é muito útil quando você abre uma conexão de banco dados e, antes de fechá-la, decide usar um "try catch()". Você pode fechar esta mesma conexão dentro do finally, assim você garante que a conexão será fechada.

Answer (score 2):

Outro caso em que você pode utilizar o finally após o try/catch, é na situação de manipular arquivos no meio do seu processo e para não encher o código com File.Delete, você pode apenas limpar a pasta no finally ou ainda gravar os caminhos e nomes numa variável e limpar antes de sair.

Comment: Outro caso? Você só pode usá-lo após um `try/catch`.

Comment: Kyllopardiun, o que quis dizer, foi em demonstrar um caso de utilização do try/catch/finally - no intuito de controlar erros e disparar e-mails de exception. Claramente, o finally é após de um try/catch.