# Yield return dentro de um using

Tags: c#, yield

Considere a seguinte situação:

```
public class MeuRecursoBemCaro : IDisposable
    {
        public T FazerOperacaoBemCara(T item)
        {
            //Do operação
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            //Dispose logic
        }
    }

public IEnumerable<T> OperarSobreMeusItens(IEnumerable<T> MeusItens)
    {
        using (MeuRecursoBemCaro recurso = new MeuRecursoBemCaro())
        {
            foreach(T item in MeusItens)
            {
                yield return recurso.FazerOperacaoBemCara(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Há certeza que meu `Dispose()` será chamado ou o `yield return` não vai deixar o `using` cair na clausula `finally` que ele cria implicitamente?

Comment: Vai passar sim!, faz assim coloque um breakpoint no `public void Dispose()` e execute normalmente seu código

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando se chama um método com `yield`, o que ele faz é criar um objeto do tipo enumerável.
O `foreach` cria um `IEnumerator<T>` através do método `GetEnumerator`.

Normalmente, quando o método acaba de enumerar todos os elementos, o código nos blocos `finally` é executado. Um `using` é equivalente a ter um `try... finally` com o `Dispose` no `finally`.

Mas nem sempre os ciclos são executados até ao fim. Um exemplo disto é quando têm `break` ou o método `Take` do LINQ.

O tipo `IEnumerator<T>` define o método `Dispose`. Quando o `foreach` acaba, este método é chamado.
O `Dispose` de enumeradores de métodos com `yield` é usado para executar código de blocos `finally`, que de outra forma não seria executado para ciclos interrompidos.

Naturalmente, caso se use o enumerador manualmente, falte o `Dispose` e não se iterar até ao fim, o código nos `finally`/`Dispose` não é executado.

É também importante notar que os métodos com `yield` podem devolver o tipo `IEnumerable` não genérico apesar desta interface **não** definir o método `Dispose`.
Nesse caso, o `foreach` tenta converter o enumerável para `IDisposable` para chamar o método `Dispose` na mesma.

Isto é, considere-se a seguinte classe:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    class MyType : IDisposable
    {
        public string Id;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disposing MyType " + Id);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> X1(string id)
    {
        using (new MyType { Id = id })
        {
            yield return 1;
            yield return 2;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End {0}", id);
    }

    public static IEnumerable X2(string id)
    {
        using (new MyType { Id = id })
        {
            yield return 1;
            yield return 2;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End {0}", id);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var i in X1("Generic loop")){ }
        foreach (var i in X1("Interrupted generic loop"))
        {
            break;
        }
        X1("Manual generic dispose").GetEnumerator().Dispose();
        X1("No Enumerator generic dispose").GetEnumerator();
        foreach (var i in X2("Old-style loop")) { }
        foreach (var i in X2("Interrupted old-style loop"))
        {
            break;
        }
        X2("No Enumerator old-style dispose").GetEnumerator();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

O output deste programa é:

```
Disposing MyType Generic loop
End Generic loop
Disposing MyType Interrupted generic loop
Disposing MyType Old-style loop
End Old-style loop
Disposing MyType Interrupted old-style loop
```

O código compilado do `Main` é equivalente a (código obtido com o [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)):

```
// Program
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (int i in Program.X1("Generic loop"))
    {
    }
    using (IEnumerator<int> enumerator2 = Program.X1("Interrupted generic loop").GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator2.MoveNext())
        {
            int j = enumerator2.Current;
        }
    }
    Program.X1("Manual generic dispose").GetEnumerator().Dispose();
    Program.X1("No Enumerator generic dispose").GetEnumerator();
    foreach (object k in Program.X2("Old-style loop"))
    {
    }
    IEnumerator enumerator4 = Program.X2("Interrupted old-style loop").GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        if (enumerator4.MoveNext())
        {
            object l = enumerator4.Current;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        IDisposable disposable = enumerator4 as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
    Program.X2("No Enumerator old-style dispose").GetEnumerator();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Marquei a sua resposta como answer pelo exemplo e pela explicação. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Não sei se há alguma outra questão implícita, mas se é só isto, não há problema algum com o `yield return`. Ele não deixa de ser um `return`. De uma maneira geral, não há maneira da rotina deixar de passar pelo `finally` implícito. Se quiser saber sobre os raros casos realmente catastróficos onde o `finally` não será executado, veja [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16065/como-e-quando-usar-o-finally-apos-um-try/16074#16074). Mas nada relacionado ao `yield return`.

Pelo menos nunca vi nada dizendo que isto fosse possível. Pelo contrário, apesar de não ter lido nada neste sentido, tudo que já vi indica claramente que em condições normais não há meio de burlar o `finally`.

Comment: Fiquei preocupado sobre uma possibilidade de que o Dispose() não fosse chamado para algumas centenas de arquivos em disco devido a uma operação que necessita de um yield return, assim criando um grande problema na minha pequena aplicação. Achei [esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405877/a-concern-about-yield-return-and-breaking-from-a-foreach) sobre um assunto quase igual ao meu, e respondido diretamente por um dos developers do C#. Sua resposta também foi útil. Valeu.