# Qual a utilidade da palavra reservada "yield"?

Tags: c#, .net, yield, palavras-reservadas

Qual a utilidade da palavra-chave (reservada) `yield`?

Quando e onde é usada?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: Pelo que pude entender seu uso seria para casos em que teria mais de um return, mas confesso que não consigo ver uma boa aplicação dos exemplos que vi no link que mandei como referência

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## TL;DR

Podemos dizer que é um [açúcar sintático](https://wikipedia.qwika.com/en2pt/Syntactic_sugar) existente desde o C# 2 para controlar fluxo de execução do programa mantendo um estado.

Ele é muito usado para dar melhor eficiência e abstração na execução de uma sequência de dados (tecnicamente esta sequência poderia ter apenas um elemento mas quanto menos elementos, mesmo ele é interessante).

Por uma questão de legado a sintaxe dele é sempre `yield return`, o mais usado, ou `yield break`.

O primeiro encerra o funcionamento de um método retornando um valor para quem chamou como é de se esperar de um `return`. Mas neste caso o valor é encapsulado em uma estrutura de dados que conta com um [iterador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) criando um [*generator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)) indicando onde ele parou para poder retomar dali.

O segundo encerra o método de forma "definitiva" encerrando o iterador.

Na verdade o `yield` é uma forma limitada de [*continuation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).

Ele controla a execução através de um estado oculto que determina em que ponto de uma enumeração o programa está executando, então a chamada consegue continuar de onde parou. Note que ele retorna um tipo enumerável e não o tipo do que você quer em si (se é para retornar um `int`, na verdade ele retorna um `IEnumerable<int>`). Esta estrutura enumerável é que controla a continuidade da execução de onde parou.

Então podemos dizer, de outra forma, que o método com `yield` retorna um valor sem sair deste método. Claro que ele sai, mas sai sabendo onde parou e sabe que tem voltar lá quando ele for invocado novamente então dá a impressão que ele nunca saiu.

Ele gera o que poderíamos chamar de coleção de dados virtual temporária que é materializada mais tarde quando os dados são necessários de fato.

## Funcionamento

[Nesse artigo do Jon Skeet](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx) mostra o funcionamento dele:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Test {
    static IEnumerator GetCounter() {
        for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
            yield return count;
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Yield.cs).

Compila para isto:

```
internal class Test {
    // Note how this doesn't execute any of our original code
    private static IEnumerator GetCounter() {
        return new <GetCounter>d__0(0);
    }

    // Nested type automatically created by the compiler to implement the iterator
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <GetCounter>d__0 : IEnumerator<object>, IEnumerator, IDisposable {
        // Fields: there'll always be a "state" and "current", but the "count"
        // comes from the local variable in our iterator block.
        private int <>1__state;
        private object <>2__current;
        public int <count>5__1;

        [DebuggerHidden]
        public <GetCounter>d__0(int <>1__state) {
            this.<>1__state = <>1__state;
        }

        // Almost all of the real work happens here
        private bool MoveNext() {
            switch (this.<>1__state) {
                case 0:
                    this.<>1__state = -1;
                    this.<count>5__1 = 0;
                    while (this.<count>5__1 < 10) {
                        this.<>2__current = this.<count>5__1;
                        this.<>1__state = 1;
                        return true;
                    Label_004B:
                        this.<>1__state = -1;
                        this.<count>5__1++;
                    }
                    break;

                case 1:
                    goto Label_004B;
            }
            return false;
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        void IEnumerator.Reset() {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose() {
        }

        object IEnumerator<object>.Current {
            [DebuggerHidden]
            get {
                return this.<>2__current;
            }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current {
            [DebuggerHidden]
            get {
                return this.<>2__current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ele não faz mágica, é apenas mais um [padrão de projeto que é tão útil que foi inserido como facilidade da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16204/101). O código se transforma em uma [máquina de estados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

No C# ele é sempre implementado através de um [`IEnumerable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) e mais recentemente através de sua [versão genérica](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0).

Embora ele possa ser usado de forma independente ele é muito usado para abstrair um *loop*. Ele executa cada passo deste *loop* dentro de um método em cada chamada dele. AO contrário da intuição do desenvolvedor quando ele vê um `return` ele acha que o método encerrou por completo. Ele até encerra. Mas a aplicação sabe em que ponto do *loop* ele está. Quando o método for chamado novamente de forma apropriada, ele sabe que estava parado naquele ponto do iterador (do *loop*) e ele continua dali, ao invés de ele começar o *loop* do zero, ele começa de onde parou. Isto se repete a cada chamada do método com `yield` até que todo o *loop* se encerre.

Por isto é muito comum que um método que tenha um `yield` dentro seja chamado como parte de um outro *loop*.

Este processo é chamado [*lazy evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) ([avaliação preguiçosa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pregui%C3%A7osa)).

Outro bom exemplo do funcionamento em uma sequência bem simples pode ser encontrada [nesse artigo](https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/).

## Utilização

Ele é muito utilizado para postergar a execução de um código. Isto permite melhorar a performance em vários cenários porque ao invés de executar todo um *loop* para iterar em uma sequência de dados ele vai passo a passo até onde precisa. E encerra definitivamente se quem chama um método achou o que precisava sem passar por todos valores. Em alguns casos toda iteração pode ser evitada. Além disto a o tempo gasto para iterar fica para o momento da real utilização.

É um recurso poderoso que poucos entendem como usar. Principalmente quando criar um *loop* desta forma. As pessoas têm mais facilidade para entender coisas concretas e isto é uma abstração que parece desnecessária. Usar um método que possui `yield` é simples mas é preciso entender que não vem todos os dados de uma vez. Criar um método que cria um iteração virtual com `yield` é um pouco mais complicada, precisa ser bem pensada.

Um exemplo:

```
// Display powers of 2 up to the exponent 8:
foreach (int i in Power(2, 8)) {
    Console.Write("{0} ", i);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> Power(int number, int exponent) {
    int counter = 0;
    int result = 1;
    while (counter++ < exponent) {
        result = result * number;
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Chame este código com *debug* ligado e ande passo a passo pelo programa para entender como ele executa. No *debug* dá para ver que depois da primeira execução o código fica sempre dentro do `while`. Aconselho fortemente fazer isto para acompanhar. Isto é um teste de mesa que parece que os programadores não aprendem mais fazer.

#### Uso prático

Um bom exemplo é encontrado [nessa resposta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/97350/389) no Programmers.SE:

```
//retorna um milhão de itens que podem ser iterados 
List<object> GetAllItems() {
    List<object> millionCustomers;
    database.LoadMillionCustomerRecords(millionCustomers); 
    return millionCustomers;
}

//chamada
int num = 0;
foreach(var itm in GetAllItems())  {
    num++;
    if (num == 5)
        break;
}
//Nota:um milhão de itens são retornados, somente 5 são usados.
```

Agora veja com `yield`:

```
//retorna cada item em cada chamada
IEnumerable<object> IterateOverItems() {
    for (int i; i < database.Customers.Count(); ++i)
        yield return database.Customers[i];
}

//chamada
int num = 0;
foreach(var itm in IterateOverItems())  {
    num++;
    if (num == 5)
        break;
}
//somente executa os 5 itens dentre um milhão existente
```

Veja que o código executa até achar o número que ele ele está procurando, no caso o 5. No primeiro código ele retorna todos os dados executando um *loop* um milhão de vezes. No segundo ele vai um por um.

Note que o método chamador não sabe se tem um `yield` no método chamado ou não. Isto é um detalhe de implementação. Mesmo assim é bom o desenvolvedor ter consciência de como ele será executado.

De outro lado o método chamado não sabe quando ele não precisará mais ser executado. ELe está preparado para executar tudo se for necessário. O método chamador é quem vai determinar quando encerrar.

Imagine que esta lista está sendo retornada por um programa com interface com usuário. Sem o `yield` todos os dados precisam ser retornados para serem mostrados na interface. Isso pode levar alguns segundos, quem sabe até em casos extremos, minutos. O usuário vai achar que de u "pau".

Com o `yield` é possível pegar elemento por elemento e já ir mostrando para o usuário sem bloquear a interface.

Como isto nem sempre é simples de fazer o C# criou uma nova abstração, um novo açúcar sintático, o [`async` e `await`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh191443(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e que ajuda montar uma máquina de estados mais complexa.

#### Outro exemplo

Na mesma resposta há outro exemplo interessante mostrando que você pode executar dois *loops* de forma concomitante intercalando seus elementos de forma mais eficiente já que cada *loop* anda um elemento de cada vez:

```
IEnumerable<object> EfficientMerge(List<object> list1, List<object> list2) {
    foreach(var o in list1) 
        yield return o; 
    foreach(var o in list2) 
        yield return o;
}
```

Na resposta existem outros exemplos que podem ser observados.

#### Comparação de performance

Fiz um exemplo gerando uma sequência de [fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) usando as duas formas.

Nele dá para perceber que o `yield` é ótimo para pegar uma quantidade limitada de dados. Mas faça um *fork* no código e mande pegar todos os dados da sequência. Você verá que a performance fica pior. Todo esse controle de fluxo e estado interno tem um custo. Se for ler toda sequência o uso do `yield` sai mais caro.

Ainda assim ele pode ser usado para melhorar a abstração. Nem sempre a performance é o mais importante.

Veja [funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w14cA3).

#### Abstração

Vamos dizer que você tem que pegar clientes de um banco de dados. A lógica para pegar esses dados pode ser um pouco complexa. Para um código que só quer ter os clientes em mãos, não interessa saber como pega os dados, só interessa que os dados estejam à mão.

Então a solução que todo bom programador usa é encapsular essa lógica complexa em um método e o código que precisar dos clientes só chama este método para ter a lista de clientes sem se preocupar com a implementação - que pode inclusive mudar sem preocupação do consumidor da lista.

Isto é uma abstração. O problema é que sempre volta a lista toda. E se você quer estabelecer algum filtro? Terá que pegar todos os dados e depois "passear" por eles para pegar o que interessa.

Com o `yield` você tem a abstração de forma eficiente possibilitando o filtro ser aplicado externamente à implementação que efetivamente pega os dados no banco de dados percorrendo só os dados necessários.

## `yield break`

Veja o código extraído [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231945/221800) no SO:

```
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    if (i < 5) {
        yield return i;
    } else {
        //quando chegar aqui ele sai do *loop* sem retornar um valor
        yield break;
    }
    i++;
}
Console.Out.WriteLine("não executa");
```

Neste caso o `yield` é necessário junto ao `break` para indicar que o estado de controle deve ser encerrado. No caso ele não sai apenas do `while`, ele encerra totalmente esse iterador sem retornar nenhum valor. É uma forma de encerrar o *loop* não permitindo que a mesma iteração continue.

Esta é a forma de dizer dentro do método que controla a iteração com o `yield` que ela não tem mais elementos para serem lidos. Assim a o *loop* do método chamador será encerrado também.

## Referências

[Documentação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) da Microsoft.

Eu respondo algo sobre isto e já tem alguma explicação [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38932/101) que inclusive tem um *link* para mostrar o funcionamento em detalhes.

[Esse artigo](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080812-00/?p=21273&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) inicia uma série que demostra o funcionamento interno por um dos melhor melhores desenvolvedores da face da Terra.

[Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16750/101) fala sobre um uso específico dele.

Também respondo sobre um outro uso dele [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19172/101).

E ainda há um dos usos mais importantes na linguagem, o LINQ todo é baseado nele, por isto as expressões não são avaliadas no momento da sua declaração e sim no momento da utilização dos dados, como demonstrado [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101).

Uma boa forma de aprender alguns usos é olhar o código fonte do LINQ no .Net. Pode começar com o [`Where()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Utils/CollectionExtensions.cs,6506ce7ce8ef56d0). Perceba o uso do `yield`. Por isto o LINQ tem vários métodos que são executados em sequência no mesmo item e só depois de executar estes métodos da expressão do LINQ é que ele vai para outro elemento da coleção de dados.

Outro [artigo interessante](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575713/What-is-the-use-of-csharp-Yield-keyword) para ler.

[Vários artigos](https://web.archive.org/web/20190113231735/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/iterators/) sobre o assunto escritos por quem fazia tudo isto funcionar no compilador.

Comment: Boa explicação.

Answer (score 13):

[**yield**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) retorna um objeto que implementa a interface **IEnumerable**, ou seja um *iterator*.

Segue um exemplo, onde `yield return` é utilizada para retornar uma lista de mensagem de validação:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Entidade novaEntidade = new Entidade();
        var mensagens = novaEntidade.ObterMensagensValidacao();
        foreach(var msg in mensagens)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }

}

public class Entidade
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> ObterMensagensValidacao()
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Nome))
        {
            yield return "O nome deve ser preenchido.";
        }

        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Telefone))
        {
            yield return "O telefone deve ser preenchido.";
        }
    }
}
```

Já `yield break` você pode utilizar para sair de uma iteração.
`yield break` especifica que um *iterador* chegou ao fim.

Exemplo:

```
public IEnumerable<int> ObterNumeros()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (i < 5) {
            yield return i;
        } else {
            yield break;
        }
            i++;
    }
}
```

Ao iterar sobre o retorno do método acima serão impressos os números de 0 a 4 conforme `yield break` utilizado.

```
    var numeros = novaEntidade.ObterNumeros();
    foreach(var num in numeros)
    {
        Console.Write(num); 
        //Serão impressos: 0 1 2 3 4
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

A palavra-chave `yield` foi adicionada à linguagem para ajudar na construção de iteradores do tipo `IEnumerable`.

Em outras palavras, existe uma máquina de estados "escondida" aí que "se lembra" da última posição que você estava dentro do contexto do seu iterador. Portanto, quando você executar o código abaixo, você vai obter o próximo valor até terminar o iterador:

```
public IEnumerable<int> IdadesImparesJovens()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 3;
    yield return 5;
    yield return 7;
    yield return 9;
    yield return 11;
    yield break;  // não necessário.. mas interessante...
}

public void VerificarIdades()
{
    foreach(int i in IdadesImparesJovens())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
```

}

É lógico que este é um exemplo muito simples, mas serve apenas para debugar. Escreva um programa console e tente debugar para verificar o que acontece nas iterações.

Neste caso, o `break` não era necessário. Mas vamos supor (e em todas as vezes que usar o `yield`) você tenha uma lógica mais complexa. Neste caso, seria interessante usar o `yield` para quebrar a sequência dos seus iteradores.

Vantagens:

- O `yield` dá a possibilidade de ler conforme avançar (lazy-loading). Construções antigas faziam com que você precisasse de um array inteiro na memória para iterar sobre ele. Com o `yield` você pode iterar e ler as informações conforme necessário (O LinQ usa muito essa construções sobre os panos);
- Ajuda a preservar o estado durante as iterações