# Consulta do banco para uma List em C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, lista

Preciso fazer uma consulta no banco, fiz esse código para conexão, mas não sei como prosseguir para colocar essas informações em uma `list<String>`

```
SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(_stringConexao);
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT CodEstabelecimento 
                                     FROM TBEstabelecimentos", conexao);

List<String> teste = new List<string>();
```

Pretendo utilizar está `List` como base para um `ComboBox`, não sei se esta é uma boa prática, se tiver outra forma mais prática eu aceito também.

Obs: Estou conectando em um banco SQLServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser só gerar a lista e se virar depois, uma forma de fazer isso seria assim:

```
public IEnumerable<string> PegaLista() {
    //cria a conexão garantindo que ela será fechada. A string é pega do arquivo de configuração
    //É possível a string de conexão pegar da fonte que você quiser
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
    //cria uma *query* garantindo que ela será encerrada ao final
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        connection.Open(); //abre conexão
        cmd.CommandText = "select COUNT(CodEstabelecimento) as contagem from TBEstabelecimentos"; //define a query p/ o DB
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) { //cria um leitor do ADO.Net
            while (reader.Read()) { //vai lendo cada item do resultado do select
                //retorna sob demanda cada item encontrado
                yield return reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("contagem"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/GetData.cs).

Se precisar gerar a lista concreta poderá fazer:

```
var teste = PegaLista();
```

Você não precisa gerar a lista concreta, pode pegar os dados diretamente através de um *binding* obtendo eficiência.

Leia [outra resposta para entender o `yield`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44315/101).

Se preferir gerar a lista de forma tradicional pode fazer:

```
public List<string> PegaLista() {
    var lista = new List<string>();
    //cria a conexão garantindo que ela será fechada. A string é pega do arquivo de configuração
    //É possível a string de conexão pegar da fonte que você quiser
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
    //cria uma *query* garantindo que ela será encerrada ao final
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        connection.Open(); //abre conexão
        cmd.CommandText = "select COUNT(CodEstabelecimento) as contagem from TBEstabelecimentos"; //define a query p/ o DB
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) { //cria um leitor do ADO.Net
            while (reader.Read()) { //vai lendo cada item do resultado do select
                //adiciona cada item encontrado na lista que será retornada
                lista.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("contagem")));
            }
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Chamando o método:

```
var teste = PegaLista();
```

Alguma coisa me dize que você não quer usar o `COUNT()` nesta *query*, ela produzirá um resultado único e não uma lista efetiva. Mas aí você avalia e troca por um campo adequado.

Com esta lista você terá ainda que criar um *binding* com o WPF. Tem várias formas de fazer isso e a melhor depende do resultado desejado.

[Nessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/561427/221800) tem um exemplo mais completo para fazer o *binding*. Ela não está mostrando como pegar do banco de dados mas mostra como a `CollectionView` pode ser *populada* com uma lista gerada conforme eu demonstrei acima.

Usar o WPF não é algo simples, você precisa entender completamente o seu funcionamento. Não dá para ir tentando fazer alguma coisa na base do "bumba meu boi" como dá com outras tecnologias. Bom, até dá para vai fazer tudo errado e vai aprender a fazer tudo torto. A melhor forma de aprender usar esta tecnologia é seguindo um bom livro (que eu saiba só existe em inglês) que detalha bem cada aspecto. Conhecimento fragmentado neste caso vai mais prejudicar que ajudar.

Esta ainda é uma forma ingênua de criar uma aplicação WPF. Uma aplicação real vai exigir mais esforço.

Um [pequeno tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301678/Step-by-Step-WPF-Data-Binding-with-Comboboxes).

Comment: Quanto ao SQL, era um exemplo para testar a conexão e não alterei... Mas valeu, acabei achando uma resposta, mas é a mesma coisa, obrigado