# Como limitar os recursos usados pelo sistema?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desempenho

Tenho um laço de repetição que faz várias iterações e possui em seu escopo cálculos que exigem muito processamento.

O problema é que ao executar o trecho do código, o uso do processador se elevar gradativamente, até travar a aplicação e posteriormente o sistema operacional.

Bem, meu objetivo é limitar de alguma forma o consumo desses recursos que levam ao travamento do sistema. Sei que isso aumentará o tempo de resposta, mas minha prioridade no momento é não travar o sistema.

> O projeto está em **Windows Forms**, mas este trecho está em uma
>   **Class Library**.

Veja um trecho do código:

```
private static string[] TodosPossiveis(char[,] letras)
{
            int linhas = letras.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
            int colunas = letras.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
            int max = (int)Math.Pow(linhas, colunas);
            string[] todos = new string[max];


            int[] posY = new int[colunas];

            int atual = 0;
            while (atual < max)
            {

                string nova = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < colunas; i++)
                {
                    nova += letras[i, posY[i]];
                }
                for (int i = colunas - 1; i > -1; i--)
                {
                    posY[i]++;
                    if (posY[i] == linhas)
                    {
                        posY[i] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                todos[atual++] = nova;
            }

            return todos;
 }
```

Este método recebe um conjunto de caracteres e devolve todas as combinações possíveis.

Tentei usar apenas variáveis primitivas para melhorar no desempenho, mas mesmo assim, ao receber um conjunto grande de caracteres o sistema acaba travando.

Comment: Já considerou processar em uma Thread separada? Com isso ele usaria o processador, mas ainda assim daria espaço para outros processos do sistema e de todo SO.

Comment: A operação trava o sistema operacional ou a sua aplicação?

Comment: Tente usar um Thread.Sleep(10); Assim o sistema da uma pausa e não consome tanto processamento.

Comment: @Ricardo como eu poderia fazer isso? Poderia formular uma resposta para que eu aceite?

Comment: @jbueno tudo começa com a aplicação não respondendo, mas em pouco tempo todo o sistema operacional fica travado.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues vc usá rodando isso como? WinFor, asp.net?

Comment: @Ricardo Windows Form, vou adicionar na pergunta.

Comment: Tenta seguir esse guia, eu precisei fazer um processamento pesado aqui e com ele eu não só liberei os processos como fiz mais rapido por usar varios so mesmo tempo. Caso tenha problemas com o guia posta o problema com o seu código que eu ajudo mais. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A primeira tarefa que deve fazer é pensar se tem uma forma melhor de executar isto, eu duvido que precise de um algoritmo tão pesado, ou ele não é tão pesado assim. Sem um contexto completo não dá para ajudar e nem é o foco da pergunta.

Avalie se não está tendo problema de memória. Sem saber exatamente onde está o problema, vai achar a solução errada.

Vou repetir, a solução real é perfilar e achar um algoritmo, e talvez estrutura de dados, melhores.

Se não consegue melhorá-lo e realmente esteja atrapalhando, então o sistema operacional é que deve ser responsável por dar mais ou menos prioridade ao processo.

Dá para fazer isto chamando o programa com [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc770297(v=ws.11)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou mandar seu próprio código diminuir prioridade com a propriedade [`Process.PriorityClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_PriorityClass). Um `BelowNormal` deve servir, ou pode exagerar e colocar em `Idle`.

A propriedade [`Process.ProcessorAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_ProcessorAffinity) pode ajudar evitando que todos os *cores* sejam usados pelo processo.

Existe a possibilidade de criar algum código que minimize isto, mas não acho uma boa solução na maioria dos casos, é gambiarra maior ainda.

Cuidado para não fazer gambiarras que parecem resolver e só pioram.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta @bigown, achei muito interessante essa possibilidade de poder controlar a prioridade do processo, você poderia falar um pouco mais sobre o assunto? Uma trhead seria uma boa opção?

Comment: Não sei se tem muito mais a falar. Não acho que precisa criar *thread* para resolver isto. Até tem algumas soluções possíveis, mas pra que? Na verdade ela pode atrapalhar, porque se hoje você não usa todos processadores, e portanto tem folga no processamento, criando *thread* ajudará ocupar tudo, que é o oposto do que você deseja. Parece que nem todo mundo entendeu isto. Você não quer aproveitar melhor o processador, que "desperdiçar" seu uso :) Eu duvido que precise de uma solução complexa, mas é possível fazer um esquema de *throttling* de uma *thread*, mas de novo, pra que? Vai no simples.

Answer (score 1):

Usando esse tutorial você vai conseguir separar esse processamento. Vai consumir o recurso da maquina, mas não vai travar a maquina, ainda via poder calcular percentual, contar o processamento, etc atualizando na tela.

Veja esse [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx)

Tendo algum problema no seu código é só dizer, podemos fazer o acompanhamento em outra pergunta se for o caso.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Muito obrigado @Ricardo esse link resolve minha vida, mas para aceitar sua resposta, preciso que fale um pouco mais detalhadamente sobre o assunto **Multithreading**. Assim, não só eu, mas outros que necessitarem, poderão seguir o passo a passo sabendo o que exatamente estão fazendo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu trabalhei em um sistema de Orçamento de Recursos Humanos que processava o orçamento da folha de pagamento de mais de 500 mil funcionários, com várias etapas de cálculo que realmente consumiam muito os recursos do sistema operacional.

A solução que encontraram foi deixar uma máquina dedicada para o cálculo, e a chamaram convenientemente de "Máquina de Cálculo". Dessa forma, o sistema ficava separado do processamento do cálculo, e permitia que o usuário solicitasse a execução do cálculo para pegar os resultados depois que já estivessem prontos.

Talvez isso funcione para você também. Então, em vez de tentar processar tudo de uma vez e já mostrar os resultados para o usuário, basta você notificar o usuário que o processamento foi iniciado e está em andamento, e depois que o processamento for concluído você notifica ao usuário e apresenta os resultados a ele. Isso pode ser tanto em arquivo, relatório ou em uma tela de seu sistema.

Comment: Eu trabalhei com uma folha que rodava em várias empresas com diversas complexidades, tinha empresa que tinha necessidades que só esse sistema resolvia. O computador existente na época era o 386. Processava cerca de 10 funcionários por segundo. Acredito que hoje processe pelo menos 1000 por segundo (provavelmente mais), o que faria esse cálculo em menos de 10 minutos. Me lembro na época que ganharam com larga folga de uma folha que famosa por ser a mais rápida do mercado :)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @ulysses-alves. Infelizmente não posso usar uma máquina dedicada, pois minha aplicação tem que rodar diretamente na máquina do cliente mesmo, mas gostei muito da ideia da notificação, vou estudar um pouco mais sobre multithreading e notificações.

Comment: Por nada. Outra possibilidade também é você criar um serviço pra ficar rodando na mesma máquina, talvez pesquisando uma tabela do banco de dados aguardando por novos dados a serem processados. Dessa forma sua aplicação continuaria com a responsabilidade apenas de atender às solicitações dos usuários, enquanto o serviço faria o processamento pesado dos dados. Creio que assim você também consegue separar as duas coisas: processamento e regras de negócios.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sei que é um post antigo, mas ainda assim tem alguns pontos que valem ser listados...

1) A carga de memória pesada e lentidão não surpreendem, uma vez que vc está tentando alocar todas as possibilidades em memória ANTES de retornar. Se vc passar um array de input de 10x10, a variável `max` será 1E10, ou 1 com 10 zeros na frente. Pense que se vc tentar alocar um array de retorno deste tamanho, ele terá no mínimo essa quantidade de consumo de bytes, o que dá uns **9,3 GIGAS** de memória para alocar isso tudo... fora o tamanho de cada palavra em si...

Um jeito de contornar isso é usar o operador `yield return`. Veja estes links:

- [Qual a utilidade da palavra reservada "yield"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44293/qual-a-utilidade-da-palavra-reservada-yield)
- https://www.dotnetperls.com/yield
- https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Com isso, vc evita alocar tudo em memória. Outro ponto é mudar o retorno para `IEnumerable<string>`.

2) No trecho `nova += letras[i, posY[i]];`, ao invés de usar o operador += use um objeto StringBuilder - [veja exemplos aqui](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder).
A cada iteração nesta linha, o .NET é obrigado a realocar memória para construir a string atual.