# Qual é o equivalente ao array_map do PHP em C#?

Tags: c#

Em *PHP*, posso criar um novo `array` baseando-me num `array` já existente, utilizando a função `array_map`.

Com ela, posso definir um callback que é responsável pelas definições de cada valor que será usado na criação desse "novo `array`".

Exemplo em PHP:

```
 $numeros = [1, 2, 3];

 $numeros_dobrados = array_map(function ($value)
 {
        return $value * 2;
 }, $numeros);


print_r($numeros); // [2, 4, 6]
```

Também sei que tem como fazer isso em `python`.

Exemplo em Python:

```
 [x * 2 for x in range(1, 10) ]

 > [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Como poderia fazer isso com esse "array" em C#?

Exemplo em C#:

```
  var arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

var arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(x => x * 2).ToArray();
```

Aqui está a implementação do `Enumerable.Range`:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count) {
    long max = ((long)start) + count - 1;
    if (count < 0 || max > Int32.MaxValue) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("count");
    return RangeIterator(start, count);
}

static IEnumerable<int> RangeIterator(int start, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) yield return start + i;
}
```

Se quiser entender um pouco mais sobre como os métodos funcionam, já que eles usam **Lazy Evaluation** (você pode notar pela palavra reservada **yield**, aqui está um link para referência:

[Qual a utilidade da palavra reservada "yield"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44293/qual-a-utilidade-da-palavra-reservada-yield/44315#44315)

Comment: Só para eu entender: `Enumerable` é uma classe, e `Range` é um método estático? Pois não houve instância... Ou `Enumerable` é o namespace e `Range` é a classe?

Comment: Enumerable é uma classe estática que lhe permite usar um método estático que retorna um um IEnumerable<int>. A vantagem do Enumerable.Range é que por usar IEnumerable ele lhe permite usar o Lazy Evaluation, que é bem útil em alguns cenários.