# Qual é a utilidade de Task.Yield?

Tags: c#, .net, assincronismo

A documentação desse método diz:

> [**Método Task.Yield()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield(v=vs.110).aspx) – adaptado do inglês
>   Cria uma tarefa *awaitável* que retorna assincronamente para o contexto atual quando *awaitada*.

Li o [código fonte dele](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,dfe9c1a07538b32f) e me perdi mais ainda!

```
public static YieldAwaitable Yield()
{
    return new YieldAwaitable();
}
```

A classe `YieldAwaitable` é descrita dessa maneira: fornece um contexto *awaitável* para mudar para um ambiente-alvo (*provides an awaitable context for switching into a target environment*).

Não entendo o uso real dele.

O que essa função de fato faz? Em que contextos esse método traria vantagens e por quê?

Essa questão se refere ao método `Task.Yield` e não à palavra-chave `yield`.

<sub>Fiz algumas traduções nessa pergunta que podem não ser muitos boas. Edições serão bem vindas.
 (1) Não sei se *aguardável* substituiria 100% a palavra *awaitable*, por isso aportuguesei a grafia.</sub>

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a utilidade da palavra reservada "yield"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44293/qual-a-utilidade-da-palavra-reservada-yield)

Comment: `yield` é uma _keyword_ utilizada em iteradores. O da minha pergunta se difere completamente. É um método do `System.Threading.Tasks`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando se usa o `async/await` não é garantido que o código vá executar de forma assíncrona, e em alguns casos, pode ser desejável que o método seja sempre executado de forma assíncrona, neste caso pode-se usar o `await Task.Yield()` para forçar ele a rodar assincronamente.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Yield(); // Faz com que o método retorne imediatamente

    var dados = ExecutaProcessoNaThreadDaInterface(); // Este código vai ser executado no futuro

    await ProcessaDadosAsync(data);
}
```

Se não usar o `await Task.Yield()` este código rodaria de forma síncrona até chegar na ultima linha, onde ele possivelmente rodaria de forma assíncrona, mas como foi feita a chamada ao `Task.Yield` ele vai forçar o código a ser executado mais tarde, sendo que quando ele for executado pode ainda acontecer de ser de forma síncrona, afinal ele vai rodar no mesmo contexto que foi iniciado, no caso na *UI Thread*