# Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, goto

Algumas linguagens, como C, ainda possuem a instrução [`goto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto).

Sempre ouvi que utilizá-la não é uma boa prática. Eu gostaria de saber:

- Quais seriam as razões para evitar o `goto` e quais os problemas causados por sua utilização?
- `goto` ainda existe por compatibilidade, ou para casos muito restritos de utilização?

Comment: Ao meu ver, um dos principais motivos é que usar GOTO demasiadas vezes deixa o código confuso. De uma olhada nas discussões a esse respeito no SO em inglês, talvez isso lhe ajude a entender. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906056/goto-is-this-bad
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Comment: Estou só aguardando uma pergunta sobre a utilidade do [**`COMEFROM`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM).

Comment: Quatro respostas até agora e ninguém citou Dijkstra e seu famoso _"Go To Statement Considered Harmful"_?

Comment: No meu caso, vou responder o motivo de eu não citá-lo: não quero que minha resposta pareça do tipo "um cara importante falou então tá falado". É importante entender por conta própria.

Comment: Além do mais, me contrariando e agora sim usando uma citação, só pelo humor, “Arrogância em ciência da computação é medida em nano-Dijkstras” - Alan Kay :-)

Comment: O objetivo de citá-lo é justamente com uma postura crítica, como o @bigown fez. Não acatar porque "um cara importante citou", mas incluir a citação pelo valor histórico.

Comment: Estamos em 1980 ?! Já foi mais que provado que é uma prática ruim de programação , linguagens modernas nem mais tem a síntaxe ... Respeito seu direito a debater mas francamente lamento o tema.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

## Resposta direta

A razão pela qual as pessoas dizem para evitar o `goto` é a legibilidade. Seria para facilitar o entendimento do código, para o programador não se perder no que o código faz. O `goto` em si não causa problema algum.

O `goto` ainda existe porque ele ainda é útil. Ele existe porque a maioria dos criadores de linguagens são pragmáticos.

## De onde veio o mito?

Basicamente, o "culpado" é o artigo "[go to statement considered harmful](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD02xx/EWD215.html)" do Edsger W. Dijkstra. Mais precisamente do seu editor, que escolheu um título muito chamativo. Depois todas as pessoas que falam do que não sabem perpetuaram o mito.

Claro que o artigo mostra uma situação em que o `goto` não precisa ser usado. Mas ele não diz que o `goto` não deveria existir. Na verdade o artigo apenas tenta vender a ideia da programação estruturada.

No passado os programas eram entendidos muito pelo seu fluxo, sejam eles em Assembly, sejam nas primeiras linguagens de alto nível. A programação [estruturada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122430/101) e modularizada surgiu pouco depois para revolucionar a programação mais um vez. Desta forma **os programas seriam entendidos pela sua estrutura e não pelo seu fluxo**. Realmente isso ficou comprovado como um enorme facilitador para o entendimento dos programas, que eram cada vez maiores.

Como o [telefone sem fio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telefone_sem_fio_%28brincadeira%29) costuma ser a brincadeira preferida das pessoas elas passaram a repetir que o `goto` fritava seu cérebro ou fazia o computador soltar bolhinhas.

## O que é um GoTo?

Pela maneira como as pessoas falam parece que a palavra/expressão `goto` é que é o problema. Um `break` ou `continue` podem ser considerados `goto`? E um `break label`? Um `return`? E o que dirá do `throw`?

O `throw` parece ser um dos comandos mais queridos dos programadores hoje em dia na maioria das linguagens. E ele pode ser considerado o pior tipo de `goto`. É difícil criar uma estrutura de controle tão pouco previsível quanto o `throw`, mas não vejo as pessoas falarem mal dela. De fato o tratamento de exceções parece ser um dos recursos mais abusados na programação neste século. Tudo bem que o abuso ocorre mais por causa do `catch` onde não se pode fazer nada útil, mas o `catch` é apenas o *label* do desvio causado pelo `goto`. Eu falo disso em vários *posts* mas parece que as pessoas que mais precisam ler essas coisas só têm tempo para postar seus probleminhas de código. Veja [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101), [melhor maneira de lidar com exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101) e [exceção](/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o).

Apesar de eu achar radicalismo que busca problemas ao invés de soluções, acho mais coerente quem acha que qualquer forma de `goto` é ruim. Preconceito com a palavra é que não dá para aceitar.

É claro que algumas implementações de `goto`, principalmente as mais antigas, podem não ser as ideais, deixa você fazer alguma maluquice que não ajuda ninguém. Mas é claro que não é problema do conceito, e sim da implementação.

## Ele não deveria existir?

```
while x < 10
    print x
    x++
end
```

É o mesmo que

```
while: if x >= 10 goto end
    print x
    x++
    goto while
end:
```

Claro que a primeira forma reduz um pouco o tamanho do código por ter um *syntax sugar*. Mas é mais difícil acompanhar o segundo exemplo do que o primeiro?

O `goto` por si só não causa problema nem mesmo de legibilidade. **O mal uso dele é que pode causar dificuldades para dar manutenção no programa**.

Pode parecer que estou defendendo o uso do `goto`. Longe disto, **você deve tentar evitar ao máximo o seu uso, mas não à qualquer custo**. A programação baseada em `goto` certamente é bem problemática, mas o uso parcimonioso do recurso por quem entende o seu funcionamento e conhece as dificuldades que ele pode impor ao seu programa não é problemático.

É irônico ver os defensores da legibilidade proporem códigos ilegíveis só para atender a "regra" que um `goto` não deve ser usado. Há quem ache que *flags* são melhores que usar um `goto`. Pode até ser em algum caso, mas não para tudo. Guardar e controlar estado de uma variável para evitar o `goto` é caso típico de aumentar a complexidade em nome da regra.

Há casos que o `goto` facilita a legibilidade, os principais já foram demonstrados nas outras respostas. Um caso bem útil é evitar o uso de múltiplos pontos de saída (`return`) como [demostrado em uma resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2478/101).

Aprendi programar usando uma linguagem que basicamente só tinha `goto`. Usei por muitos anos uma linguagem que o mais perto do `goto` era apenas o `break` e `continue`. Hoje uso **linguagens que não incentivam seu uso, mas permitem usar de forma limitada. Este é o ponto**. Nem me lembro quando foi a última vez que usei o famigerado, mas gosto de saber que posso usá-lo quando precisar.

Odeio linguagens que querem proteger o programador não permitindo fazer o que pode ser útil. Você apenas força a utilização de estruturas mais complexas que serão bem feitas, na medida do possível, pelos bons programadores, e serão muito mal feitas pelos outros programadores. A ausência de `goto` na linguagem limita os bons programadores e não resolve nenhum problema real.

- Linguagens que não possuem `goto` complicam a vida de quem precisa criar geradores de código para estas linguagens alvo.
- Não ter `goto` promove construções complicadas não padronizadas, especialmente na criação de máquinas de estado.
- Pode reduzir a facilidade para otimizações realmente necessárias em códigos que precisam arrancar o máximo da performance.
- A falta do `goto` aumenta a complexidade ciclomática em muitos casos.

É uma pena que uma linguagem como o JavaScript, que é tão [usada como *target* de outras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102787/101), não tenha um `goto` nativo.

Algumas linguagens limitam ou podem limitar, acertadamente, o que o `goto` pode fazer:

- certamente o `goto` não deveria pular partes importantes do código;
- não deveria poder entrar dentro de um escopo forçadamente;
- algumas pessoas acham que não deveria permitir voltar o fluxo para traz.

O `goto` pode ser usado de uma forma estruturada. [Donald Knuth sabe bem disto](https://web.archive.org/web/20200825025335/https://cs.sjsu.edu/%7Emak/CS185C/KnuthStructuredProgrammingGoTo.pdf). Quem sou eu para contestá-lo. Não é o uso do `goto` que se opõe à programação estruturada. O abuso dele sim.

Outro que dá boas dicas de como usar o `goto` adequadamente é o Stece McConnel no [Code Complete](https://web.archive.org/web/20170214113252/https://www.stevemcconnell.com/ccgoto.htm).

Talvez a explicação mais completa, não necessariamente a melhor, sobre o assunto esteja [nesse artigo](http://david.tribble.com/text/goto.html).

Ninguém é obrigado a concordar com tudo o que eu ou essas pessoas escreveram. Eu não concordo com tudo. Mas existem fatos e boas observações.

Evitar o `goto` pode ser tão danoso quanto usá-lo. Em geral um `goto` vale mais do que violar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

## De qual linguagem estamos falando?

O AP cita a linguagem C. Esta é uma linguagem que precisa muito do `goto` para fazer limpeza de recursos, liberação de memória, encerramento de operações. Alguém pode reclamar que isso é um problema da linguagem. Mas ele não deixa de ser útil e é isso que importa.

Existem linguagens que não possuíam nenhuma forma de `goto` e depois passaram ter. Porque viram utilidade.

Cada linguagem tem uma necessidade. Algumas precisam mais que outras, mas todas podem se beneficiar dele em maior ou menor grau.

Sem saber de qual linguagem estamos falando, só podemos dizer que o `goto` é útil sim. Conhecendo a linguagem, podemos dizer com mais precisão onde ele é útil.

Não vou falar de linguagens já faladas em outras respostas, e obviamente não falarei de linguagens que não domino.

## Usos legítimos no C#

De acordo com a [referência da Microsoft para o comando](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), alguns usos legítimos são:

```cs
class SwitchTest {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Coffee sizes: 1=Small 2=Medium 3=Large");
        Console.Write("Please enter your selection: ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        int n = int.Parse(s);
        int cost = 0;
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                cost += 25;
                break;
            case 2:
                cost += 25;
                goto case 1;
            case 3:
                cost += 50;
                goto case 1;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection.");
                break;
        }
        if (cost != 0) Console.WriteLine("Please insert {0} cents.", cost);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Um caso comum em C# é colocar o `goto case <próximo caso>`. Ele é uma forma de *fall through*, já que o C# não possui esse recurso automático, ou seja, um bloco `case` precisa terminar com `break` ou `goto`. Algumas pessoas acham que o C# deveria ter o *fall through* automático para reduzir um tamanho do código. Outras dizem que isto causa *bugs*.

Outra forma:

```cs
public class GotoTest1 {
    static void Main() {
        int x = 200, y = 4;
        int count = 0;
        string[,] array = new string[x, y];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                array[i, j] = (++count).ToString();
        Console.Write("Enter the number to search for: ");
        string myNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                if (array[i, j].Equals(myNumber)) goto Found;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The number {0} was not found.", myNumber);
        goto Finish;
    Found:
        Console.WriteLine("The number {0} is found.", myNumber);
    Finish:
        Console.WriteLine("End of search.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Em algumas linguagens que não possuem a palavra reservada `goto` isso pode ser obtido por `break label`. Mas só porque não tem a palavra `goto` ele deixa de ser problema? Saltar mais de um nível de um *loop* aninhado é algo que o comando ajuda. As tentativas de evitá-lo, em geral, levam a um código pior.

É provável que a linguagem seria menos criticada se criasse um `break label` para resolver esses dois casos. Isso mostra que o ódio ao recurso é irracional. De qualquer forma, outras formas ainda seriam proibidas e é uma limitação indesejável.

Uma limitação desejável e existente na linguagem é a **proibição do *label* estar em um escopo mais interno que do `goto` ou em outro escopo**. Não há como entrar dentro de um *loop* através do `goto`, por exemplo. Sair dele não é problema, porque é o `goto` que está mais interno, e não o *label*. Isto não é possível:

```cs
var a = 1;
var s = "";
if (a == 1) {
    s = "1";
    goto label1;
} else if (a >= 2) {
    s = "2";
    goto label1;
} else {
    label1:
    s += "3";
}
```

Obviamente **sair de um método com `goto` não é permitido**.

Um *label* não pode ser um último [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) (sim, o *label* é um *statement*) de um método. Precisa ter algo depois dele mesmo que seja apenas um `return` ou um *statement* vazio (`;`).

**Dentro de um `finally` não pode existir um `goto`**.

O `finally` será executado mesmo que um `goto` tente evitá-lo. O `finally` tem prioridade e o * label* de um `goto` só receberá o fluxo do programa quando todos os `finally`s envolvidos forem executados.

```cs
try {
    ...
    goto label1;
} finally {
    CloseAll();
}
label1:
    FazAlgo();
```

Neste caso o `CloseAll()` será executado antes do `FazAlgo()` [indubitavelmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16074/101).

Um [exemplo achado no Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/18643/468) em que a resposta aceita é pior que a que usa `goto`:

```cs
string errorMessage;
while(!TryTableFill(myDataTable, out errorMessage)) {
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Can't load data:\n" + errorMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    if(result != DialogResult.Retry)
        break;
}

private boolean TryTableFill(myDataTable, out string errorMessage) {
    errorMessage = string.Empty;
    try {
       oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable);
       return true;   
    } catch (Exception ex) {    
       errorMessage = ex.Message;
       return false;
    }       
}
```

Aparentemente (não pra mim) é melhor que:

```cs
start:
try {
    oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Can't load data:\n" + ex.Message, "Error",
        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    if (res == DialogResult.Retry)
        goto start;
}
```

Jura que evitar o `goto` no código abaixo deixou o código mais legível?

```cs
var tryAgain = true;
while (tryAgain) {
    try {
        ...
        tryAgain = false;
    } catch (...) {
        tryAgain = true
    }
}
```

Com `goto`:

```cs
tryAgain:
    try {
        ...
    } catch (...) {
        goto tryAgain;
    }
```

Já vi casos em que o programador colocou um *loop* e pelo menos 2 desvios incondicionais (qualquer combinação de `break` e `continue`) para evitar um simples, inocente e legível `goto`.

## Exemplo de mal uso

```cs
var retVal = false;
if(cond1)
    goto exit;
if(cond2)
    goto exit;
if(cond3)
    goto exit;
retVal = true;
exit:
return retVal;
```

Pode ser substituído por:

```cs
return !(cond1 || cond2 || cond3);
```

Procure usar o `goto` para expressar sua intenção e não como um mecanismo. Neste caso a intenção não precisava de `goto` e nem de uma estrutura complexa. O problema aqui nem é o `goto`. Veja a versão dele sem o uso do comando do capeta e que continua ruim:

```cs
if(cond1)
    return true;
if(cond2)
    return true;
if(cond3)
    return true;
return false;
```

## Conclusão

Programadores ruins vão produzir códigos ruins, não importa se usa `goto` ou não. É lamentável ver casos de `goto` onde existe uma construção melhor. Mas é pior ainda ver código ruim porque uma regra cega foi usada.

O `goto` pode ser útil para:

- Tornar o código mais fácil de ler.
- Reduzir o tamanho do código.
- Evitar repetição de código.
- Facilitar código gerado automaticamente.
- Sair de *loops* aninhados.
- Manipular máquinas de estado.
- Garantir uma saída limpa de uma rotina.

Dieta manda você comer menos e com mais qualidade para cuidar da sua saúde, não manda você não comer. Cuide de sua saúde e use um pouquinho, bem pouquinho de `goto`, sempre que ele beneficiar mais do que atrapalhar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Goto.cs).

[Mais um exemplo em pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/322636/101).

Comment: Exceções também causam bastante discussão. É só ver as discussões sobre a linguagem Go, que prefere retornar códigos de erro, embora também tenha algo parecido com exceções com os nomes de panic, recover, e defer.

Comment: @nbro Justamente porque o pragmatismo puxa pela utilidade e não por purismos ou conceitos inventados por alguns que não fazem sentido.

Comment: Por isso algumas linguagens não são pragmáticas, eles dizem que você não pode usar, mesmo que tenha um uso legítimo. Tem que ver o código pra poder dizer, eu conheço um monte de gente que nunca precisou usar `goto` e os códigos deles são bem mais complicados do que deveriam e eles nem conseguem enxergar isto.

Comment: Obrigado. Nem sempre consigo fazer tão bem, mas sempre tento fazer o melhor que dá. O melhor elogio que recebi aqui foi que eu não sou reducionista, até sou um pouco, mas menos do que o pessoal costuma ser, que acaba criando um problema porque programação não é seguir receitas. E para mostrar como fazer e não só dar a receita exige respostas mais completas. Nem todo mundo gosta disto. Há quem reclame das minhas respostas. Talvez porque elas prefiram que os demais não evoluam por conta própria, que sempre precisem ficar dependendo dos outros.

Answer (score 27):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>*Imagem original: [xkcd 292](http://xkcd.com/292/)*</sub>

É raro encontrar situações em que você precise utilizá-lo, mas eu não descartaria completamente o seu uso.

Embora o uso de `goto` **quase sempre** seja uma má prática de programação (*com certeza você pode encontrar uma modo melhor*), há momentos em que ele realmente não é uma má escolha. Alguns podem até argumentar que, quando é útil, é a melhor escolha.

Considere o seguinte exemplo, em Delphi.

```pascal
uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

Var
 Nomes : array[0..6] of string = ('João', 'Maria', 'Ciclano', 'Marialva', 'foo', 'bar', 'bazz');
 Indice: Integer; 
Const
 meuNome = 'Ciclano'; 

label encontrouValor;
 
 Begin
 for Indice := 0 to Length(Nomes) -1 do begin   
   if (Nomes[Indice] = meuNome) then
     goto encontrouValor;   
 end;

encontrouValor:
 MessageBox(0, pchar(Format('%s está na posição %d', [Nomes[Indice], indice])), '', MB_OK);
end.
```

Se o conteúdo da constante `meuNome` existir na *array* `Nomes`, a mensagem irá aparecer conforme o esperado, mas e se não existir? Bom, no exemplo acima o resultado será algo semelhante a isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse exemplo, a utilização do `goto` é uma péssima escolha, mas e se estabelecermos uma condição `if...else`*?*

```pascal
Var
 Nomes : array[0..6] of string = ('João', 'Maria', 'Ciclano', 'Marialva', 'foo', 'bar', 'bazz');
 Indice: Integer;

Const
 meuNome = 'Maria';

 label encontrouValor, naoEncontrou;
 
Begin
 for Indice := 0 to Length(Nomes) -1 do begin 
 MessageBox(0, pchar(Nomes[indice]), '', 0);  
   if (Nomes[Indice] = meuNome) then 
     goto encontrouValor
   else
     goto naoEncontrou
 end;

encontrouValor:
MessageBox(0, pchar(Format('%s está na posição %d', [Nomes[Indice], indice])), '', MB_OK);

naoEncontrou:
MessageBox(0, pchar('O seu nome não existe na lista'), '', MB_OK);
end.
```

Teríamos novamente um fracasso, nesse caso o primeiro nome da lista seria exibido na mensagem(*erroneamente*) e logo em seguida a mensagem dizendo que o nome não existe na lista. Um modo mais elegante desse exemplo sem a utilização do `goto` seria algo como isso:

```pascal
Var
 Nomes : array[0..6] of string = ('João', 'Maria', 'Ciclano', 'Marialva', 'foo', 'bar', 'bazz');

function fooBar(meuNome: string; var Posicao: integer): Boolean;
Var
 Indice: Integer;
begin
Result := False;

for Indice := 0 to Length(Nomes) -1 do begin 
    if (Nomes[Indice] = meuNome) then begin
       Posicao := Indice;
       Result  := True;     
    end;
end;  
end;

Var
 Pos: Integer;
 Nome: string = 'Maria';
Begin
if fooBar(Nome, Pos) then
   MessageBox(0, pchar(Format('%s está na posição %d na lista', [Nome, Pos])), '', MB_OK)
else
   MessageBox(0, pchar(format('%s não existe na lista', [Nome])), '', MB_OK or MB_ICONERROR);   
 
Readln; 
end.
```

Situações em que o uso do `goto` pode ser considerável:

***Loop* aninhado**: Considere que em uma função tenha múltiplos *loops*(*while, for, repeat, etc*) e necessite sair de todos os *loops* o `goto` pode vir a calhar em situações como essa.

```pascal
Var
 IndiceI, IndiceII, IndiceIII: Integer;

label exitLoop; 

Begin
for IndiceI := 0 to 100 do begin 
    for IndiceII := 0 to 100 do begin
        for IndiceIII := 0 to 100 do begin 
          if(IndiceII = 73) then
             goto exitLoop;
        end;
    end;
end;

exitLoop:
 Writeln('Fora do loop');
 Readln;
end.
```

**Limpeza de recursos**: Considere que em uma determinada função você precisa alocar alguns recursos, e haja a necessidade de verificar algumas condições, tal como o resultado de uma outra função ou os parâmetros passados para a nossa função, considere o exemplo abaixo.

```pascal
procedure foo;
Var
 FS: TFileStream;
 HI: HINTERNET;
 SE: TShellExecuteInfo;

label exitFuncao;
begin
{
  Alocação dos objetos:
     fs := TFileStream.Create('C:\foo\bar.baz');
     hi := InternetConnect();
     SE := SE.cbSize := SizeOf(SE);
}
if (GetLastError = ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_URL) then begin
  FreeAndNil(FS);
  FreeAndNil(HI);
  FreeAndNil(SE);
end else if (GetLastError = ERROR_INTERNET_PROTOCOL_NOT_FOUND) then begin
  FreeAndNil(FS);
  FreeAndNil(HI);
  FreeAndNil(SE);
end else if (GetLastError = ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT) then begin
  FreeAndNil(FS);
  FreeAndNil(HI);
  FreeAndNil(SE);
end else if {.....}
end;
end;
```

Não seria mais fácil simplificar a limpeza dos recursos uma única vez? O uso do `goto` serviria muito bem nessa situação, em que você necessite sair em vários pontos da função. Veja:

```pascal
procedure foo;
Var
 FS: TFileStream;
 HI: HINTERNET;
 SE: TShellExecuteInfo;

label exitFuncao;
begin
{
  Alocação dos objetos:
     fs := TFileStream.Create('C:\foo\bar.baz');
     hi := InternetConnect();
     SE := SE.cbSize := SizeOf(SE);
}
if (GetLastError = ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_URL) then goto exitFuncao
 else if (GetLastError = ERROR_INTERNET_PROTOCOL_NOT_FOUND) then goto exitFuncao
  else if (GetLastError = ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT) then goto exitFuncao;
   {else if ...}
    {else if ....}
     {else if .....}

exitFuncao: begin
  FreeAndNil(FS);
  FreeAndNil(HI);
  FreeAndNil(SE);
end;
end;
```

Comment: Lembrando que Delphi tem `try .. finally`, então o goto não seria necessário nesse caso. Por isso prefero mencionar C como exemplo. A menos, claro que estejamos falando de “Pascal pré-exceções”, nesse caso sobra só o goto mesmo.

Answer (score 18):

**`goto INICIO;`**
**`FIM:`**

Em conclusão: Se você pode escrever sem usar gotos, prefira. Mas se você fizer isso e notar que o código ficou maior e pior, não tenha medo de voltar atrás.

**`goto SAIR;`**
**`MEIO:`**

O exemplo clássico:

```
int do_some_operation() {
    struct something1 smt1;
    struct something2 smt2;
    struct something3 smt3;
    int result;

    if (initialize_something1(&smt1) == FAILURE)
        return FAILURE;

    if (initialize_something2(&smt2) == FAILURE) {
        delete_something1(&smt1);
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if (initialize_something3(&smt3) == FAILURE) {
        delete_something2(&smt2);
        delete_something1(&smt1);
        return FAILURE;
    }

    result = do_work(&smt1, &smt2, &smt3);

    delete_something3(&smt3);
    delete_something2(&smt2);
    delete_something1(&smt1);
    return result;
}
```

Aqui temos 3 recursos, totalizando 4 pontos de saída da função. Em cada ponto é preciso limpar os recursos de forma diferente. Agora considere que temos mais recursos, mais operações que podem falhar, argumentos, etc.

Observe como é melhor escrever assim:

```
int do_some_operation() {
    struct something1 smt1;
    struct something2 smt2;
    struct something3 smt3;
    int result;

    if (initialize_something1(&smt1) == FAILURE) { result = FAILURE; goto finish0; }
    if (initialize_something2(&smt2) == FAILURE) { result = FAILURE; goto finish1; }
    if (initialize_something3(&smt3) == FAILURE) { result = FAILURE; goto finish2; }

    result = do_work(&smt1, &smt2, &smt3);

finish3: delete_something3(&smt3);
finish2: delete_something2(&smt2);
finish1: delete_something1(&smt1);
finish0:
    return result;
}
```

A concordancia geral é que você deve procurar outras formas de escrever o código e evitar o uso de goto. Mas tem de tomar cuidado para não meramente evitar gotos a todo o custo. Talvez eles sejam sim a melhor forma de resolver o seu caso específico.

Mais um exemplo útil:

No linux, ao utilizar system calls, pode acontecer de durante a execução no sistema o processo receber um sinal. Nesse caso a chamada é interrompida imediatamente e o sinal é processado. No fim, ela retorna no erro `EINTR` que meramente indica que você deve chamar a função novamente.

```
restart:
    if (system_call(arg1, &arg2) == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR) goto restart;
        if (errno == OTHERERROR) ...;
    }
```

Escrever isso de outra forma requereria um laço e não ficaria muito legível.

**`goto FIM;`**
**`INICIO:`**

Em linguagens de maior nível e que possuam orientação a objetos realmente não faz sentido utilizar GOTO. Eles quebram o fluxo de leitura e não são necessários para fazer limpeza já que é bastante aceitável que cada recurso deve ter um dono e deve ser destruído quando o seu dono for destruído (por seu respectivo dono ou por algum mecanismo de coleção de lixo).

No entanto, quando você desce de nível até o assembly, nota que não existem loops, condicionais, ou mesmo funções. Tudo é feito com gotos. A linguagem C foi criada com performance em mente. Sendo assim faz todo o sentido que seja possível trabalhar do mesmo jeito que no assembly. Como aqui você não tem uma divisão clara de objetos, é um pouco mais complicado determinar o momento certo para fazer a limpeza.

**`goto MEIO;`**
**`SAIR:`**

Achou a organização da resposta ruim? Não deixe seu programa assim.

Comment: Quem sabe a organização da resposta ficou ruim, mas só para quem não tem noção do goto e leu a tua resposta sem prestar atenção, eu achei tão normal quanto as outras :D

Answer (score 17):

**Antes de linguagens estruturadas**, existiam linguagens que continham basicamente 2 estruturas de decisão/controle: `if` e `goto`. Além disso, podiam ter no máximo o recurso de funções e o loop `for`, e acabava por aí mesmo. Estou pensando em linguagens como os primeiros FORTRANs e BASICs, e deve haver muitas outras que ficaram esquecidas na história.

Ah, sim: dependendo da linguagem o `if` só podia conter 1 instrução, não existia `else` e os rótulos das linhas eram sempre números. Era basicamente tudo com if e goto. Qualquer bloco abstrato do tipo "execute estas 10 instruções até que tal condição ocorra" ficava na cabeça do programador original, porque para ler o código era necessário acompanhar linha a linha para onde o goto ia saltar. Os "blocos" não eram evidentes pela estruturação do código.

Por isso era necessário ter todo o código do programa na cabeça, já que de qualquer lugar poderia saltar para qualquer outro lugar, alterar qualquer variável e voltar para qualquer outro lugar. Devia ser bem difícil de ler.

**Linguagens mais modernas** permitem estruturar melhor o código: do/while/for para loops, if com else, funções que recebem parâmetros, retornam valores e podem ter suas próprias variáveis locais para cálculos intermediários.

Então ficou claro que é muito mais fácil programar numa linguagem estruturada, porque ela expressa melhor a intenção do programador e permite **ler e entender trechos menores de código** antes de partir para o próximo trecho. Por isso o goto ficou com má-fama, como símbolo das linguagens não-estruturadas e de código confuso.

Outro problema também é que o goto pode ser um pouco tentador para iniciantes: pode parecer mais fácil à primeira vista mandar um goto para qualquer lugar do que estruturar um loop com uma condição de saída no início ou no fim do bloco. Inclusive as primeiras implementações de Pascal não tinham nem `break` nem `continue`, mas depois dessa época a maioria percebeu que também não precisava chegar a tal ponto (porque alguns loops ficam bem legíveis com o teste no meio seguido de `break`) e muitas linguagens hoje têm `break`, `continue` como "gotos restritos" e o caso do `goto` genérico fica a critério do designer da linguagem.

Concluindo: é importante aprender a usar bem todas as outras estruturas: while, do/while, for,  break, continue, funções (imagine como ficaria horrível simular funções só com `goto`s), e para aqueles casos em que nada mais servir, não há problema em usar um goto aqui ou lá, sempre em último caso. Na linguagem C, geralmente é a situação de "deu tudo errado, saia de todos os loops, libere a memória e termine a função", enquanto que nessa situação outra linguagem poderia recomendar o uso breaks nomeados ou de exceções. Cada linguagem tem sua peculiaridade.

Comment: Abençoadas sejam as linguagens de alto nível. Phew!

Answer (score 15):

## Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?

> O *goto* tem capacidades exclusivas de tornar um código ilegível.

## Quais seriam as razões para evitar o GOTO e quais problemas causados pela sua utilização?

Vou listar abaixo quais recursos das linguagens de programação tem o potencial de tornar o código ilegível:

- **Todos.**

E um dos recursos que eu tenho visto melhor desempenhando esta função de tornar o código ilegível não é nem o GOTO mas sim o simpático **IF**, por exemplo em códigos com IF aninhado:

```cs
if (...) then
    // ...
else if (...) then
    // ... 
        if (...) then
            // ... 
                if (...) then
                    // ... 
        else
            // ...
```

Mas enquanto todos os recursos da linguagem podem ser mal utilizados, **o GOTO, quando mal utilizado, tem poderes especiais de causar estragos:**

- **GOTO é o único que não tem delimitação clara de começo e fim**, (*{ }*), ou seja, GOTO pode ser usado para escrever blocos de código mas pode ser usado também para escrever código recursivo e loops difíceis de serem identificados como tal.
- **GOTO é o único que pode te enviar para dentro de um loop em um contexto difícil de prever**. Pois é, o GOTO não pode te enviar para dentro de estruturas formais de loops (*for*, *while*), mas se o próprio GOTO pode produzir loops e um GOTO pode te enviar para dentro de qualquer label, então o GOTO pode sim enviar o ponto de execução do código para dentro de loops.
- **GOTO é o único que não tem escopo de variáveis**. Os outros blocos de código possuem seu próprio escopo de variáveis, enquanto com o GOTO eu posso pular para depois da declaração de uma variável e atribuir e incrementar o valor dela lá, de lá eu faço outro GOTO para antes da declaração da variável e quando a execução finalmente chegar na linha da sua declaração e primeira atribuição de valor (`int i = 1`), aquilo que, pela ordem das linhas e pelo comando que se está lendo parece ser o primeiro uso da variável, está na verdade sobrescrevendo um valor previamente setado.
- **GOTO é o único que permite um fluxo arbitrário para o código** (*labelA -> labelB -> labelC -> volta para labelB -> vai para lugar nenhum*). As demais estruturas (loops, ifs, métodos) possuem um ponto de entrada e um marcador de fim, quando então a execução retorna para o chamador. Um GOTO te manda para outra linha que pode ou não resultar depois na execução da linha seguinte, e você só vai conhecer a condição para a linha seguinte ser executada se você estudar cada linha subsequente ao label para o qual o GOTO te mandou (estas linhas, por sua vez, podem te mandar para outros labels).

Por estas características especiais o GOTO tem habilidades mais poderosas de deixar um código difícil de entender.

## O motivo do GOTO ainda existir seria por questões de compatibilidade ou um caso muito restrito de utilização?

A resposta pode ser outra pergunta:

> Se todos os recursos da linguagem tem o potencial de tornar o código ilegível, por que matar o GOTO?

Alguém que aprendeu a fazer código bacana com o GOTO em outras linguagens pode querer fazê-lo também em C#.

## Exemplos de bom uso do GOTO em uma linguagem estruturada moderna

Isso eu ainda não encontrei. Ainda mais se orientação a objetos for suportada, usar o GOTO parece muito desnecessário e sempre há opções mais expressivas sem ele.

Para sua apreciação e avaliação imparcial, vou tomar como exemplo os códigos da [documentação da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) (os mesmos usados na resposta do @Maniero) e ver como eles ficariam sem o GOTO:

### Transferir o controle para um *label* específico em um *switch-case*

O exemplo da Microsoft, usando GOTO é assim:

```cs
class SwitchTest {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Coffee sizes: 1=Small 2=Medium 3=Large");
        Console.Write("Please enter your selection: ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        int n = int.Parse(s);
        int cost = 0;
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                cost += 25;
                break;
            case 2:
                cost += 25;
                goto case 1;
            case 3:
                cost += 50;
                goto case 1;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection.");
                break;
        }
        if (cost != 0) Console.WriteLine("Please insert {0} cents.", cost);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Vejamos como fica este código sem o GOTO:

```cs
class SwitchTest {
    static void Main() {
        const int priceSmall = 25;
        const int priceMedium = priceSmall + 25;
        const int priceLarge = priceSmall + 50;
        Console.WriteLine("Coffee sizes: 1=Small 2=Medium 3=Large");
        Console.Write("Please enter your selection: ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        int n = int.Parse(s);
        int cost = 0;
        switch (n)
        {
            case 1:
                cost = priceSmall;
                break;
            case 2:
                cost = priceMedium;
                break;
            case 3:
                cost = priceLarge;
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection.");
                break;
        }
        if (cost != 0) Console.WriteLine("Please insert {0} cents.", cost);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Será que `cost += 50; goto case 1;` é mais expressivo que `cost = priceLarge;`? A segunda opção me parece mais clara, mais simples e mais expressiva.

Sem contar que, já que a linguagem suporta orientação a objetos, enumeradores, generics, polimorfismo, sobrecarga de métodos... então existem mil outras maneiras de escrever este código mais expressivo do que usando GOTO e mais expressivo até mesmo do que usando *switch-case*.

### Quebrar loops profundamente aninhados

O segundo exemplo da Microsoft demonstra o uso do GOTO para quebrar todos os loops aninhados de uma vez:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    // Procura *myNumber* em um array multidimensional: 
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            if (array[i, j].Equals(myNumber))
            {
                goto Found;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The number {0} was not found.", myNumber);
    goto Finish;
Found:
    Console.WriteLine("The number {0} is found.", myNumber);
Finish:
    Console.WriteLine("End of search.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Vamos ver como fica este código sem o GOTO:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    // Procura *myNumber* em um array multidimensional: 
    var Found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < x && !Found; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y && !Found; j++)
        {
            Found = array[i, j].Equals(myNumber);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The number {0} {1}.", myNumber, Found ? "is found" : "was not found");
    Console.WriteLine("End of search.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Em vez de usar GOTO para quebrar os loops, eu usei uma variável. Se alguém disser que o código com o GOTO é mais claro eu não vou discutir, mas para mim é evidente que sem GOTO ficou mais simples.

### Conclusão sobre estes dois exemplos da Microsoft

Assim como a maioria dos exemplos da Microsoft, estes dois exemplos com GOTO procuram apenas demonstrar o potencial de um recurso e não indicam uma maneira de utilizá-lo na vida real.

## Um exemplo onde o GOTO pareceria salvar a pátria do código expressivo

Ainda aproveitando os exemplos do @Maniero, este código bastante esquisito:

```cs
string errorMessage;
while(!TryTableFill(myDataTable, out errorMessage)) {
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Can't load data:\n" + errorMessage, "Error", 
        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    if(result != DialogResult.Retry)
        break;
}

private boolean TryTableFill(myDataTable, out string errorMessage) {
    errorMessage = string.Empty;
    try {
       oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable);
       return true;   
    } catch (Exception ex) {    
       errorMessage = ex.Message;
       return false;
    }       
}
```

é com certeza melhor substituído por este outro com GOTO:

```cs
start:
try {
    oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Can't load data:\n" + ex.Message, "Error",
        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    if (res == DialogResult.Retry)
        goto start;
}
```

De fato o uso do GOTO tornou mais expressivo e simples o código anterior. Mas quem faça questão de um código mais expressivo e não sabe que o GOTO existe, também pode resolver assim, sem GOTO:

```cs
var keepTrying = true;
while (keepTrying) {
    try {
        oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable);
        keepTrying = false;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        keepTrying = MessageBox.Show("Can't load data:\n" + ex.Message, "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.Retry;
    }
}
```

No final o código sem GOTO ficou no mínimo tão expressivo quanto o código com GOTO. Decidir qual dos dois é mais expressivo me parece questão de opinião.

## Uso de GOTO para implementar máquina de estado

Se orientação a objetos está disponível (e no foco desta resposta ela está pois os exemplos são todos em C#), um excelente exemplo de máquina de estado, muito simples, expressivo, e que passa bem longe dos GOTO pode ser encontrado nesta resposta do SO: [Simple state machine example in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924053).

Uma outra resposta para aquela mesma pergunta faz uso do GOTO. Depois o autor que usou o GOTO editou a resposta adicionando um monte de comentários no código "apenas para clarificar", enquanto a resposta que não usa GOTO não depende de nenhum comentário e eu desafio alguém a não entendê-la :D

Além disso, a resposta que usa orientação a objetos pode ser facilmente estendida e modificada com a simples edição de enumeradores e um dicionário - ela poderia até mesmo ser genérica e ser configurada por uma base de dados! Já a máquina de estado usando GOTO precisa ter seu próprio algoritmo modificado para poder ser estendida.

## Conclusão

O *goto*:

- Não é útil para tornar o código mais fácil de ler pois há outras opções mais legíveis ou pelo menos tão legíveis quanto.
- Pode ser útil para reduzir o tamanho do código mas código expressivo e de fácil manutenção é mais importante que código curto.
- Não é mais útil para evitar repetição de código do que o encapsulamento do código em loops formais, em métodos e em objetos.
- Não é mais útil para sair de loops aninhados do que declarar uma variável de controle e testar seu estado na declaração de cada loop.
- Não é mais útil para implementar máquina de estado do que a orientação a objetos.

Veja, **programadores que não nasceram experientes em algum momento vão produzir código ruim com qualquer recurso da ferramenta**.

Estes programadores podem sim se orientar por boas práticas bem argumentadas para poder desde cedo produzir bom código e ir compreendendo melhor os porquês e questionando estes porquês ao longo da carreira.

Portanto, a fim de ajudar estes profissionais, algumas vezes chamamos de "má prática" as práticas que historicamente mostraram trazer mais malefícios que benefícios. Por exemplo: disponibilizar globais para alteração de estado, capturar exceções sem saber por que, micro-otimizar código sem evidências da necessidade, dar nomes pouco significativos aos artefatos, usar herança como primeira opção...

Por fim, se o GOTO é um destes elementos com maior potencial de causar prejuízo e se existem sempre ótimas opções que o tornam dispensável como eu procurei demonstrar nesta resposta, então **usar GOTO pode sim ser considerado uma má prática**. É lógico que, assim como qualquer outra má ou boa prática, esta também sempre estará aberta a discussões.