# Utilização do BREAK dentro de um while

Tags: php, metodologia

Oi.

Tenho uma função em php que retorna N valores do banco de dados.
Para cada dado retornado eu devo fazer uma verificação de validade, e caso uma delas não passe pela validação, é desnecessário validar as demais.

É uma boa pratica de programação colocar um break dentro do laço para que o programa não fique validando os demais registros?

Answer (score 4):

Sim é uma boa prática.

Deixe bem claro onde essa linha de código está para não ser dificil de fazer debug caso tenha um problema e não veja que a linha lá está.

Sempre que houver iterações desnecessárias, quebrar o loop é bom, não só em PHP.

Comment: eu tinha escudado o inverso. por isso da pergunta. até é algo relacionado com multiplos return dentro da mesma função.

Comment: @GustavoEmmel, se tiver um exemplo pode colocar na pergunta. Se fôr para impedir iterações a mais, o break vale a pena. Multiplos returns pode ser caso de código que precisa ser re-estruturado.

Comment: bem na real é como vocÊs tão falando o meu codigo, e a ideia que tive foi justamente evitar essas iterações. mas talvez seje uma pratica melhor delimitar na consulta sql.

Comment: @GustavoEmmel relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20660/por-que-o-uso-de-goto-%C3%A9-considerado-ruim/20874#20874. As pessoas falam muita coisa sem entender o contexto. Break é um goto mais controlado. Ele é ruim quando vira bagunça, mas para simplificar código e demonstrar a intenção, é ótimo.

Comment: Eu acho que não apenas é uma boa prática, como junta e opostamente com/ao `continue`, são as únicas opções para se sair de um laço sem se apoiar num contador externo. Não sei se o `goto` do PHP serve pra isso também.

Answer (score 3):

Sim é uma boa prática evitar iterações desnecessárias, uma opção caso não queira utilizar o `break` por questões de legibilidade, seria utilizar uma variável auxiliar para testar o loop, exemplo:

```
$valido = true;
$n = 0;
//Enquanto menor 10 e válido
while ($n < 10 && $valido){
  echo $n; 
  echo PHP_EOL;
  if($n == 5) { // sua validação
    $valido = false;
  }
  $n++;
}
```

**[Exemplo](https://ideone.com/pEbB4n)**