# Pra que serve uma Label em Kotlin?

Tags: característica-linguagem, kotlin

Num exemplo de *loops* na [documentação do Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html), temos alguns códigos com o seguinte trecho:

```
loop@ for (i in 1..100) {
    for (j in 1..100) {
        if (...) break@loop
    }
}
```

Pelo que li na documentação, parece tratar-se de uma *Label* e que elas podem ser colocadas em qualquer tipo de expressão, conforme o texto:

> Any expression in Kotlin may be marked with a label. Labels have the form of an identifier followed by the @ sign, for example: abc@, fooBar@ are valid labels (see the grammar). To label an expression, we just put a label in front of it

Mas em nenhuma linguagem que eu programei até hoje houve necessidade de fazer algo parecido num trecho de código referente a uma estrutura de repetição.

Eu não entendi a função desse `loop@` no início e o `@loop` no caso dos exemplos apresentados na documentação (principalmente o desse `for` do exemplo).

- Qual é a finalidade dessas *labels* numa expressão?
- Tem a ver com GOTO? Ou é algo apenas como o `region...endregion` do C#?
- Por que no início do código o `@` está depois da palavra `loop` e, em seguida, está no início?

Comment: alguém com um inglês melhor que o meu poderia traduzir o trecho da documentação a anexar à pergunta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É uma [forma de *goto*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101), embora alguns não gostem de usar essa palavra :). Como as pessoas têm preconceito com a palavra, só pode usar com [`break`, `continue` e `return`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html) que as pessoas aceitam melhor, mas o mecanismo é o mesmo. Claro que tem algumas restrições de como pode usar, o que é algo bom para evitar maluquices no código.

O *label* é o endereço no código para onde deve ir o desvio.

No seu exemplo seria bem complicado fazer uma lógica que quebre da maneira deseja, teria que criar uma *flag* que nunca é algo bom de se fazer, introduz estado desnecessário para acompanhar.

É raro ser necessário, mas é bom ter o recurso para casos assim. Além do que, se a linguagem for usada como alvo de outra é importante ter esse tipo de característica para melhor gerar códigos.

O C# preferiu o `goto` mesmo, o Java tem só o `break` nominado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isso é GOTOfobia

Answer (score 5):

Serve pra nomear o bloco de código. É como um `goto`.

O seu exemplo é bom para ilustrar, se a condição do `if` for atendida o **`for` externo** será parado. Se não existisse um `label` especificando-o, seria o **`for` interno** que iria parar.

Answer (score 2):

É preciso entender que, no código exemplificado, a label tem como finalidade de marcar o início da expressão, no caso o `for (i in 1..100)`.

A vantagem disso é que é possível parar o primeiro loop dentro do segundo loop. Ou seja, você pode referenciar o primeiro escopo a partir do segundo.

Um pequeno esboço de como isso funciona poderia ser mostrado assim:

```
  parent:
    children:
        if (condition)
            parent.break()
```

No exemplo da sua pergunta, é utilizado o  `break@loop`. Com o `@loop` refere-se ao primeiro for, então o mesmo será parado quando atingir a condição de `if` que está dentro do segundo `for`.

Se a label não fosse utilizada, o `break`iria parar apenas o segundo `for`,  o que talvez não fosse o comportamento desejado. Se não fosse assim, provavelmente teríamos que dar uma grande volta para conseguir parar o primeiro `for` a partir do segundo.

> Qual é a finalidade dessas Labels numa expressão?

Como foi dito em outras respostas, é semelhante ao `GOTO` que existe em algumas linguagens.

A *Label* é como um ponto de partida. Quando a mesma é referenciada, você está referenciado o ponto em que a mesma foi definida.

> ... Ou é algo apenas como o region...endregion do Csharp?

Não há nenhuma ligação com funcionalidades similares a `region` ou `endregion` do C#, visto que `region` tem como finalidade de apenas demarcar um trecho de código para facilitar a diminuição de um trecho. Neste caso, `region` não afeta a execução do código, já o *Label* afeta.

> Por que no início do código o @ está no final da palavra loop e, em seguida, está no início?

O arroba no final da expressão indica que você está declarando a Label para aquele trecho do código. Já quando a mesma é referenciada usa-se no início.