# Como referenciar o primeiro loop a partir do segundo em um encadeamento de loops?

Tags: php, loop, for

Em PHP, como posso fazer para referenciar o primeiro `for` a partir do segundo, como no exemplo abaixo?

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 

    for ($j=0; $j < 10; $j++) { 

        // Quero que esse afete o primeiro `for` e não o segundo
        if ($j == $i) continue;

        echo $j;
    }
}
```

Eu aprendi a fazer isso usando a linguagem [Kotlin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227419/pra-que-serve-uma-label-em-kotlin), mas existe alguma forma de fazer algo parecido no PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um número no `continue` para identificar qual loop quer parar/continuar.

Isso funciona para `break` e `switch` também. E é contado de dentro para fora, por exemplo: o laço mais interno é o 1.

Exemplo:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    echo 'externo' . PHP_EOL;

    for ($j=0; $j < 3; $j++) { 

        // Quero que esse afete o primeiro `for` e não o segundo
        if ($j == $i) continue 2;

        echo "$i - $j" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso227789)

Comment: Uma dúvida: isso funciona da mesma forma para o `break`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Sim, cabei de editar =D

Answer (score 2):

Sim, podes usar `continue 2;`, podes ver isso na [documentação sobre estruturas de controle](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.continue.php).

> O continue aceita um argumento numérico opcional que diz quantos níveis de laços aninhados deve pular. O valor padrão é 1, saltando para o final do laço atual.

Esta funcionalidade funciona também para `break` e `switch`, e conta-se de dentro para fora, ie: o laço interior é o `1`.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < 10; $j++) { 

        if ($j == $i) continue 2;
        echo $j;
    }
}
// dá: 001012012301234012345012345601234567012345678
```

**Ideone: https://ideone.com/ga4Vzo**

Comment: wow....hahaha!!!

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar assim, Deve resultar

```
 if ($j == $i) continue 2;
```

**No manual do PHP:**

> O continue aceita um argumento numérico opcional que diz quantos
>   níveis de laços aninhados deve pular. O valor padrão é 1, saltando
>   para o final do laço atual... [Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

A mesma coisa se aplica ao **[break](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.break.php)**.

> break aceita um argumento numérico opcional que diz quantas estruturas
>   aninhadas deverá interromper. O valor padrão é 1, somente a estrutura
>   imediata é interrompida.