# Comando "goto" criando loop infinito no laço "for"

Tags: c, loop, struct, for

Quero simular um banco de dados escolar que recolhe nome, notas de matemática e física e calcula a média de ambas para 5 alunos (definidos numa *string* da `struct`).

Qualquer nota acima de 10 seria permitida, sem nenhuma trava para tal. Alunos facilmente teriam notas acima de 10. Pensei então em fazer uma condição com `if-else` e usei o `goto`, posicionando o retorno dele no início da solicitação de nota.

Vejam o código a seguir:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(void){

setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

struct Aluno{
    char nome[10];
    float notaMath, notaPhysics, media;
};

struct Aluno aluno[5];

int contador;

//Entrada de dados via teclado
for(contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++){
    printf("Nome do aluno %d: ", contador+1);
    scanf("%s",&aluno[contador].nome);

    RETORNO1:
    printf("Nota de matemática: ");
    scanf("%f",&aluno[contador].notaMath);
    if(aluno[contador].notaMath > 10.0){
        printf("Apenas notas até 10.\n");
        goto RETORNO1;
    }
    else{
        goto POINT1;
    }

    POINT1:
    RETORNO2:
    printf("Nota de física: ");
    scanf("%f",&aluno[contador].notaPhysics);
    if(aluno[contador].notaPhysics > 10.0){
        printf("Apenas notas até 10.\n");
        goto RETORNO2;
    }
    else{
        goto POINT2;
    }

    POINT2:
    aluno[contador].media = (aluno[contador].notaMath + aluno[contador].notaPhysics)/2;

    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n\n");

printf("------------Informações dos Alunos------------\n");
for(contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++){
    printf("Nome do aluno %d: %s\n", contador+1, aluno[contador].nome);
    printf("Nota de matemática: %.1f\n", aluno[contador].notaMath);
    printf("Nota de física: %.1f\n", aluno[contador].notaPhysics);
    printf("Média das notas: %.1f\n", aluno[contador].media);
    printf("\n\n");
}
}
```

Nesse caso, ao colocar quaisquer valores sem ponto flutuante maiores que 10, ele imprime "apenas notas até 10" e realmente retorna para o ponto estabelecido, tudo ok. Mas, caso eu coloque algum valor de ponto flutuante, tipo 10.5, ele entra em *loop* infinito.

Sem a colocação dos `goto` e os `POINT`s e `RETORNO`s ele simplesmente pula boa parte das instruções seguintes e vai lá pra frente no laço `for`.

Exemplo de execução (dados copiados do `.exe`):

```
"Nome do aluno 1: Jonathan
 Nota de matemática: 10.5
 Nota de física:
 Nome do aluno 2: Nota de matemática:"
```

Comment: E por que não tira esse `goto`? Não vi vantagem nele.

Comment: Deveria tirar aquele else ali realmente não tem vantagem alguma...

Comment: Posso até tirar, sem problema algum. Mas, eu queria saber uma forma de limitar o usuário a colocar notas até 10, e fazê-lo voltar à inserção da mesma nota, caso ele insista em colocar um valor maior que 10.

Comment: Até onde eu sei, o C me obriga a usar Else caso eu use If. Se existe uma forma de usar If sozinho, tipo no Java, me ensinem! haha

Comment: Sim você pode retirar o if e não é necessário colocar o else não amigo, porque você não tem uma contraproposta pra condição..

Comment: @Matheus você tem razão. Testei aqui e o If funcionou sozinho. Eu lembro lá do começo quando comecei com o Dev Cpp, que ele não deixava rolar If sem Else. To usando CodeBlocks aqui e nunca testei isso. Realmente foi trauma do Dev e falta de curiosidade em testar se funcionaria xD

Comment: De toda forma, o erro do Loop continua :( Alguma sugestão alternativa pra limitar o usuário e fazê-lo retornar à inserção da mesma nota?

Comment: Acabei de postar uma resposta.. Ve se você meio que consegue entender ela

Comment: Cuidado com a maneira que esta usando o `goto`. Nao é uma boa pratica usar dessa maneira. Fica muito confuso para outra pessoa entender fazendo esses saltos malucos de um ponto do codigo para o outro como voce fez.

Comment: Leituras obrigatórias sobre `goto`: http://bioinfo.uib.es/~joemiro/teach/material/escritura/gotoharmfulCol.pdf ; http://web.archive.org/web/20090320002214/http://www.ecn.purdue.edu/ParaMount/papers/rubin87goto.pdf

Comment: Obrigado pelo toque @gfleck. Já li um pouco sobre o goto e que não é legal usar bastante, mas não consegui pensar em outras alternativas. Por isso vim até vocês haha

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões de leitura, @JeffersonQuesado. Lerei tudo!

Comment: Uma dica de vida:
Nunca utilize goto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom como você quer fazer com que o usuário reescreva na mesma casa, caso a nota > 10, você pode fazer o seguinte, neste trecho de código você pode diminuir seu contador, desta forma ele irá voltar o para o mesmo endereço:

```
scanf("%f %f",&aluno[contador].notaPhysics, &aluno[contador].notaMath);
if(aluno[contador].notaPhysics > 10.0 || aluno[contador].notaMath > 10.0){
    printf("Apenas notas até 10.\n");
    contador--;
}
```

Mas se vocÊ quiser usar o Goto, sugiro que retire seus RETORNO1 e RETORNO2 e tambem remova os else.

Comment: Genial! Vou testar aqui

Comment: Ok caso for usar este método de decrementar o contador, remova os Goto

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Sua contribuição ajudou a resolver meu problema

Answer (score 3):

O código tinha alguns erros que eu corrigi. Melhorei um pouco o estilo também.

[`goto` quase nunca é adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101). Quase sempre pode ser substituído por um `if` ou um `while`, o que é o caso. O que deseja claramente é um laço de repetição até que a pessoa digite o correto, então faça um laço, é muito mais simples. Só saia dele quando o valor digitado for válido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    struct Aluno {
        char nome[10];
        float notaMath, notaPhysics, media;
    } aluno[5];
    for (int contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++) {
        printf("Nome do aluno %d: ", contador + 1);
        scanf("%s", aluno[contador].nome);
        while (1) {
            printf("Nota de matemática: ");
            scanf("%f", &aluno[contador].notaMath);
            if (aluno[contador].notaMath > 10.0) printf("Apenas notas até 10.\n");
            else break;
        }
        while (1) {
            printf("Nota de física: ");
            scanf("%f", &aluno[contador].notaPhysics);
            if (aluno[contador].notaPhysics > 10.0) printf("Apenas notas até 10.\n");
            else break;
        }
        aluno[contador].media = (aluno[contador].notaMath + aluno[contador].notaPhysics) / 2;
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n------------Informações dos Alunos------------\n");
    for (int contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++) {
        printf("Nome do aluno %d: %s\n", contador+1, aluno[contador].nome);
        printf("Nota de matemática: %.1f\n", aluno[contador].notaMath);
        printf("Nota de física: %.1f\n", aluno[contador].notaPhysics);
        printf("Média das notas: %.1f\n", aluno[contador].media);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jGdtQQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xuhkvrmh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Loop/Validation.c).

Eu deixei o `contador`, mas prefiro `i`, acho muito verboso, todo mundo sabe o que é o `i`, acho até mais legível. Teria outras dicas para escrever código melhor, mas foge do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Conheço o i também. Foi mais por questão de gosto, mas na maioria das vezes eu escrevo i. Entendi bem, meu amigo. Estou testando aqui! Muito obrigado

Comment: Amigo, uma pergunta. Até hoje já devo ter esbarrado umas 2 vezes com esse `while(1){ }`
O que significa essa condição? Sempre construo Whiles com variáveis e toda aquela condição de `>`, `<`, `==` e etc. 
Obg desde já

Comment: É possível fazer um `while` com variável aí, mas acho que fica um código pior. Ele é um `while` infinito, só sai forçadamente, a condição é sempre verdadeira (1).

Comment: seu `while` super funcionou! Agora, o único problema que me está sendo causado e ainda não consegui descobrir como resolver é a questão do ponto flutuante, que causa um loop infinito louco na execução. Se puder, experimente executar aí o Código completo adicionando o pedaço que você sugeriu e no momento da inserção de uma das notas, coloque um número de ponto flutuante, tipo 10.4 ou 11.3.

Veja o que acontece x_x

Comment: Isto é outro problema, faça um problema de cada vez.Demonstre em nova pergunta. Não consigo imaginar como possa causar um *loop* infinito por causa disto. É claro que valores acima de 10 não passam na validação, é o que você deseja.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: @JonathanÁlex pena que você não gostou das dicas.