# Uso de 'break' em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Por exemplo, se tenho o seguinte código:

```
var i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        if (j === 3) { break; }
        text += "The number is " + j + "<br>";
    }
}
```

Ao usar break, ele interrompe o laço do **`j`** e o resultado fica:

```
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 1
The number is 2
```

Quero saber se existe algum tipo de `break` que interromperia o **`j`** e o **`i`** de modo que o resultado fosse:

```
The number is 1
The number is 2
```

Consegui, com um `if` e uma variável, contornar esse problema. Porém, se existe um comando como o `break`, seria melhor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode usar um label no `for` externo e usar o `break` com esse label:

```js
var i, j, text = "";
a: for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        if (j === 3) { break a; }
        text += "The number is " + j + "<br>";
    }
}
document.write(text);
```

Clique no botão azul "Executar" acima para testar isso.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o que se chama [*labeled break*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break). No fundo é um *goto* um pouco mais restrito. Ele diz para onde deve ir o código quando fizer a quebra, e obviamente precisa de uma "etiqueta" no código dizendo onde é o local:

```js
var text = "";
fim: for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        if (j === 3) break fim;
        text += "The number is " + j + "<br>";
    }
}
console.log(text);
```

Também dá para encerrar a execução do algoritmo por completo, isto é possível dentro de uma função (prefiro esta solução, sem nenhum tipo de *goto*):

```js
function Finaliza() {
    var text = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
            if (j === 3) return text;
            text += "The number is " + j + "<br>";
        }
    }
    return text;
}

console.log(Finaliza());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Break.js).

Relacionado: [Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101) (defendo o *goto* no lugar certo e muitas pessoas acham que eu adoro *goto*, na verdade eu o odeio, só não acho que o ódio da maioria seja racional, já que as pessoas aceitam o *break* etiquetado que é um *goto*).

Answer (score 4):

Acho que não existe um "*break* tudo", mas você pode jogar esse laço em uma função e finalizá-la, isso contornaria o problema:

```
function ExibirNum(){
    var i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
            if (j === 3) 
                return;
            text += "The number is " + j + "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```