# Como contornar um 'problema' com GOTO em PHP

Tags: php, linux, windows, terminal

Eu tenho um pequeno gerenciador de pacotes no terminal de uso próprio e que gerencia meu Framework, e estou dando uma melhorada nele, e cai em um problema onde não consigo loopar sem usar goto, como no código abaixo:

```
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$rs_add_deps = fgetc($stdin);
$requires = [];
if ($rs_add_deps == 's') {
    add_req:
    echo "Digite o pacote completo:";
    $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
    $countReq = count($requires);
    $requires[$countReq] = fgetc($stdin);
    goto test_add_req;
} else {
    end_add_req:
    var_dump($requires);
}
test_add_req:
echo "Adicionar outro pacote?";
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$add_n_pack = fgetc($stdin);
if ($add_n_pack == 's') {
    goto add_req;
} else {
    goto end_add_req;
}
```

Esse script vai adicionando os possíveis pacotes a array `$requires[]` de acordo com o que o usuário define que quer, funciona perfeitamente, sabendo que a interação é via terminal e que nunca vou saber quantos pacotes são e (ele faz uns testes pra saber se o pacote é válido mas limpei pra ficar mais simples o exemplo), existe um modo menos torto de captar esses valores e adicionar na array?

Outra segunda solução que tenho é esta, porém achei bem mais complexo do que utilizando o goto:

```
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$rs_add_deps = fgetc($stdin);
$requires = [];
$countReq = 0;
$ask = false;
if ($rs_add_deps == 's') {
    while (true) {
        if (is_numeric($countReq) === 0) {
            echo "Digite o pacote completo EX: 'gm/bv4fphp':";
            $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
            $requires[$countReq] = fgetc($stdin);
            $ask = true;
            $countReq += 1;
        } elseif (is_numeric($countReq) > 0) {
            if ($ask == true) {
                echo "Adicionar outro pacote?";
                $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
                $add_n_pack = fgetc($stdin);
                if ($add_n_pack == 's') {
                    $ask = false;
                } else {
                    $countReq = 'get-out';
                }
            } else {
                echo "Digite o pacote completo:";
                $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
                $requires[$countReq] = fgetc($stdin);
                $ask = true;
                $countReq += 1;
            }
        } else {
            var_dump($requires);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

OBS: Esse projeto é estruturado, 0 de orientação, não queria sair deste contexto neste projeto.

Comment: Tipo usar um `while(true)` e dar `break` quando a entrada for diferente de `s`?

Comment: Você pode criar funções. Mas considerando que esse seu script é bem simples, não vejo problemas em deixar como está, se funciona. [GOTO não é o demônio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20660/por-que-o-uso-de-goto-%C3%A9-considerado-ruim) :)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu tentei com while(true), porém achei mais complexo do antes

Comment: Decidi deixar a minha contribuição com [uma imagem](http://php.net/manual/en/images/0baa1b9fae6aec55bbb73037f3016001-xkcd-goto.png) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, eu realmente não entendo porque tantos `fopen`, um basta, e a operação continua com `fgetc` dentro de um `while` ou então em uma recursão com funções, ou seja você esta abrindo várias vezes o `php://stdin` sem necessidade, você poderia simplesmente usar algo como:

```
<?php
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

while (!feof($stdin)) {
    var_dump(fgetc($stdin));
}
```

Pronto, você esta em um loop infinito já, ou você poderia simplificar mais ainda e usar diretamente a [**constante `STDIN`**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php), assim:

```
<?php
while (!feof(STDIN)) {
    var_dump(fgetc(STDIN));
}
```

---

### Agora vamos ao seu código

O seu problema nem foi com o `while` ou `goto`, é que existem falhas em seu códig que podem ser ou não o motivo de não funcionar como deseja, por exemplo:

```
echo "Digite o pacote completo EX: 'gm/bv4fphp':";
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
```

Aqui você pede que digite um caminho, mas em seguida usa:

```
$requires[$countReq] = fgetc($stdin);
```

Que irá só retornar a primeira letra e não o caminho completo, pois `fgetc` retorna somente o primeiro caractere de algo digitado

Creio que o que você deseja seja algo próximo a isto:

```
<?php
$requires = [];

function pegar_resposta()
{
    return trim(fgets(STDIN));
}

function adicionar_pacotes()
{
    global $requires;

    if (empty($requires) === false) {
        echo "Adicionar outro pacote?";
        $resposta = pegar_resposta();

        if ($resposta === 's') {
            return;
        }
    }

    echo "Digite o pacote completo EX: 'gm/bv4fphp':";

    $resposta = pegar_resposta();

    if ($resposta === 's') {
        return;
    }

    $requires[] = $resposta;

    adicionar_pacotes();
}

adicionar_pacotes();

print_r($requires);
```

É bem simplificado mesmo, a função a seguir criei para que você tenha os ajustes somente em um local:

```
function pegar_resposta()
{
    return trim(fgets(STDIN));
}
```

E o trim é para remover os espaços e quebras de linhas, para que possa pegar o `s` quando desejar terminar.

Com `while` ficaria assim:

```
<?php
$requires = [];

function pegar_resposta()
{
    return trim(fgets(STDIN));
}

while (true) {
    if (empty($requires) === false) {
        echo "Adicionar outro pacote?";
        $resposta = pegar_resposta();

        if ($resposta === 's') {
            break;
        }
    }

    echo "Digite o pacote completo EX: 'gm/bv4fphp':";

    $resposta = pegar_resposta();

    if ($resposta === 's') {
        break;
    }

    $requires[] = $resposta;
}

print_r($requires);
```