# Existe em Python Comando Similar ao (Catch and Throw) do Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

Existe em Python Algo Similar ao (Catch and Throw) do Ruby?
Gostaria de pular assim:

```
a = 10
throw :pularparaaqui if a == 10

catch :pularparaaqui do
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar ao "catch" e "throw" de várias linguagens, em Python temos o 
os blocos "try"/"except"  e o comando "raise"   --
No entanto o uso que você está fazendo no seu exemplo é basicamente o do comando "goto", que existe em C, em Basic, e é universalmente reconhecido como uma péssima prática de programação. [Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20660/por-que-o-uso-de-goto-%C3%A9-considerado-ruim/20681)

Esse uso, como você descreve, não é permitido em Python.
O mecanismo de controle de fluxo permite que, se você levantar uma exceção com o comando "raise", o processamento pula para o próximo bloco "except" que especifique aquela exceção - *só que* isso só acontece se  a exceção ocorrer dentro de um bloco "try".
O bloco não precisa estar visível no mesmo escopo em que você está escrevendo - ele pode estar no código que chama a função onde está o "raise" (ou mesmo várias camadas 'acima') - mas o bloco do except tem que estar no mesmo escopo do bloco "try".

Ainda um outro detalhe é que em geral especializamos as Exceções, criando subclasses de "Exception" - mas isso não é estritamente necessário.

```
class MinhaExcecao(Exception): pass

try:
     if a == 10:
         raise MinhaExcecao
     ...
except MinhaExcecao:
    # código continua aqui.
```

Answer (score 0):

Em `Python` existem as palavras reservadas [`try`, `raise` e `except`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) que servem exclusivamente para tratamento de `exceções`.

No caso exemplificado em sua pergunta, não existe a necessidade de um controle de exceções para "pular" o fluxo, você simplesmente pode usar um bloco `if/else` equivalente, veja só:

```
if( a == 10 ):
   print("a == 10");
else:
   print("a != 10");
```

Ou:

```
if( a != 10 ):
   print("a != 10");
else:
   print("a == 10");
```

Comment: Nada a ver. Queo algo como o goto.

Comment: @thegrapevine: Me desculpe, não gosto de [Spaghetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code), é uma questão de gosto.

Comment: Sua pergunta já foi amplamente discutida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863309/the-equivalent-of-a-goto-in-python) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python), talvez ilumine seu caminho.