# Uso correto do "goto" com o "if else"

Tags: php, if, estilo-de-codificação, else, goto

Estou com uma dúvida sobre o correto uso do "goto", fiz um pequeno exemplo que ilustra minha dúvida:

```
<?php
    $valor01=10;
    $valor02=8;
    if($valor01 > $valor02)
    {
        echo "valor01 é maior que valor02<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        goto rotulo;
    }

    rotulo:
    {
        echo "valor02 é maior que valor01";
    }
?>
```

Como fazer para que o rótulo só seja executado caso a condição do `if` não seja satisfeita?

Da forma como está o resultado é o seguinte:

```
valor01 é maior que valor02
valor02 é maior que valor01
```

Isso é possível?

Comment: O goto não é recomendado, por ser difícil de compreender quando o projeto fica maior.

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/images/0baa1b9fae6aec55bbb73037f3016001-xkcd-goto.png](http://php.net/manual/en/images/0baa1b9fae6aec55bbb73037f3016001-xkcd-goto.png)

Comment: E só pôr o código direto no else, sem goto. É pra isso mesmo que serve o else...

Comment: Neste teu exemplo não há o menor sentido usar `goto`, basta fazer a lógica dentro do `else`, de fato, creio que nunca precise usar este comando, visto que ele cria um código espaguete.

Comment: Plenamente possível é só fazer um teste de mesa que você descobrirá os trechos de seu código que serão executados. O comando goto existe por razões históricas. Era muito utilizado no estilo de programação da década de 1960 mas depois disso seu uso foi execrado por todos os problemas que causa. No seu caso é só colocar outro goto após o if pulando o trecho sob rotulo.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (assim que aceitar ganhará privilégio para votar).

Comment: Se ainda assim for ealmente necessário, OOP, não use o goto, crie uma função e chame-a no else. Evoluimos.. hehe

Answer (score 3):

Sim, existe, e muito mais simples:

```
<?php
    $valor01 = 10;
    $valor02 = 8;
    if ($valor01 > $valor02) echo "valor01 é maior que valor02<br>";
    else echo "valor02 é maior que valor01";
?>
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Qo2cGB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/viauzsyr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/If.php).

O correto uso do `goto` é evitá-lo sempre que ele não traz vantagens claras e seu exemplo ele só traz desvantagens. E até me parece que está procurando um jeito de usar um `goto` e não querendo resolver um problema. Pra que complicar o que é simples?

Relacionada: [Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101).

Comment: Maniero não se trata de tentar "reinventar a roda", ou tão pouco é "um jeito de usar goto e não querendo resolver um problema..."
Como disse, estou reaprendendo,vi a opção goto e quero entender mais a respeito dela,acredito que se foi incluída no PHP deve ter algum propósito.
O artigo que você recomendou eu já havia lido,porém acredito que seja sempre bom  ouvir mais opiniões a respeito.
O exemplo que citei é apenas para ilustrar uma hipótese,pois apesar de não ser especialista em PHP também não entendi direito o objetivo do uso da função.
Mas seja como for, obrigado pelo retorno.