# Como sair do laço FOR dentro da estrutura Switch?

Tags: c#, for, switch

Estou dentro de um laço `FOR` e quero fechar ele dentro do `Switch`, mas quando dou `break` dentro do `Switch` ele sai do `Switch` e continua o laço `FOR`, alguém pode me dizer como posso sair do laço `FOR`?

Eis o código:

```
bool variavel = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        switch (variavel)
        {
            case true:
            {
                break; // este break vai fechar o switch e não o laço
            }
            break; // este break não funciona e nunca é usado, por causa do break de cima            
            case false:
            {
            }
            continue; // continue funciona e retorna para o laço para que ele continue
        default:
            break; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estes são dois esboços que podem ou não ser aplicaveis ao seu código, mas elaborei com alternativa ao que já foi postado. Tem que analisar o resto do código para ver qual opção cabe, pois depende de como você usa a variável do loop, se tem alguma operação depois do `switch`, essas coisas que só dá para saber com o código real onde vai ser aplicada a solução.

Postei duas possibilidades complementares - a primeira executa qualquer coisa que esteja dentro do loop depois do `break` uma última vez, e a segunda sai do *loop* direto do case sem fazer mais nada no `for`:

### Finalizando o próprio *loop* :

A maneira mais usual de sair de um `for` é não satisfazer sua condição (e é o que acontece na maioria das vezes, num loop normal). Podemos usar isso a nosso favor.

Aqui você definiu uma condição para o *loop* continuar:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Se a condição é `i < length`, qualquer valor igual ou maior que `length` para `i` faz sair ao final do *loop*.

Assim, basta fazer `i = length` antes do `break` desejado:

```
bool variavel = true;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    switch (variavel)
    {
        case true:
        {
            i = length;
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Pronto, a condição para continuar o loop foi desfeita
            break; // este break vai fechar o switch e não o laço
                   // mas o laço em si vai terminar por causa da linha anterior
        }
        case false:
        {
        }
        continue; // continue funciona e retorna para o laço para que ele continue
    default:
        break; 
    }
    // Esta parte aqui ainda sera executada uma ultima vez
    // apos o case true
}
```

### Usando `goto`:

Uma saída que pode ser interessante nesses casos é o `goto`.

Veja o exemplo da própria [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto) (adicionei alguns comentários):

```
public class GotoTest1
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int x = 200, y = 4;
        int count = 0;
        string[,] array = new string[x, y];

        // Initialize the array:
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)

            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                array[i, j] = (++count).ToString();

        // Read input:
        Console.Write("Enter the number to search for: ");

        // Input a string:
        string myNumber = Console.ReadLine();

        // Search:
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                if (array[i, j].Equals(myNumber))
                {
                    goto Found; // AQUI VOCÊ ESCOLHE O DESTINO
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The number {0} was not found.", myNumber);
        goto Finish;

    Found: // ESTE É UM LABEL, VOCÊ  DEFINE O NOME DESEJADO
        Console.WriteLine("The number {0} is found.", myNumber);

    Finish: // ESTE É UM LABEL, VOCÊ  DEFINE O NOME DESEJADO
        Console.WriteLine("End of search.");

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Peguei o exemplo original para evitar erros de digitação. No seu caso vai ficar mais simples ainda:

```
bool variavel = true;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    switch (variavel)
    {
        case true:
        {
            // Se vai sair do loop, não precisa fechar o switch
            // faz o que tem que fazer e...
            goto CaiFora;
        }
        case false:
        {
        }
        continue; // continue funciona e retorna para o laço para que ele continue
    default:
        break; 
    }
    // Esta parte aqui sera totalmente ignorada
    // apos o goto
}
CaiFora:
    // Aqui continua o código normalmente
```

Leitura complementar:

> [Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20660/70)

Comment: Não sabia desse recurso, programando e aprendendo!

Answer (score 6):

Você pode tentar colocar uma outra condição no `for`

```
bool forceExit = false;
for (int i = 0; i < length && !forceExit; i++)
{
...
}
```

Quando quiser sair do for `forceExit=true`

Comment: Não me passou isso pela cabeça rs

Answer (score 4):

Extraia a funcionalidade dos seus laços agrupados e disponibilize em uma função.
Desta forma você pode usar 'return' para sair do laço de qualquer lugar, em vez de utilizar 'break'.

Utilizando seu exemplo original:

```
bool variavel = true;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   switch (variavel){
      case true: break; //Entendo que este seja o ponto de quebra desejado, correto?
      default: break;
   }
}
```

Poderia utilizar desta forma:

```
bool verificaSeVerdadeiro(bool variavel){
   switch (variavel){
      case true: return true;
      default: return false;
   }
}
```

```
bool variavel = true;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   if(verificaSeVerdadeiro(variavel)) break;
}
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339142/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-at-once-in-c

Don't panic ^_^