# Funcionalidade do ":" no C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, sintaxe

Recentemente estava desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# com o Visual Studio e me deparei com uma situação um tanto quanto inusitada:

```
public void Upload(object model)
{
    FOO:
    var text = "teste";
}
```

No código, `FOO:` não aparece como erro, e qualquer coisa que eu coloque antes dos `:` o compilador continua aceitando, mesmo sem estar comentado ou algo do gênero, porém se eu coloco isso depois da declaração da variável, por exemplo, ai começa a dar erro normalmente.

#### Desta maneira da erro

```
public void Upload(object model)
{
    var text = "teste";
    FOO:
}
```

Para que serve esta funcionalidade?

Comment: Uso C# a anos e nunca me questionei sobre isso, ótimo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O `:` é usado em diversos contextos e cada um pode ter uma diferença de significado.

Neste contexto ele é um indicador de finalização de um *label*.

Um *label* é um símbolo que marca uma posição qualquer no código (ou uma posição mais específica dentro de um comando `switch`, mas não no caso apresentado). Ele é usado para em algum comando `goto` poder especificar para onde o fluxo do código deve ir. Esse símbolo não é diferente de um nome de variável ou nome de função.

O `goto` é um comando de desvio de fluxo de execução incondicional, portanto ele muda para o local do *label*, sempre que a execução passar por ali. Sua utilidade é limitada e [bastante questionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101), por isso deve-se evitar até que tenha um bom motivo para usar.

Não usando o `goto` não tem porque ter o *label*. Nos exemplos eles servem para nada e podem ser retirados. Mas se deixar não causa mal algum, a não ser o fato de que outro programador achará muito esquisito isso no código.

Depois de compilado isso desaparece, é só indicativo do código. No lugar do *label* e do `goto` será usado o endereço do local do código onde estava o *label*, no caso o `FOO`.

O motivo do erro no segundo exemplo é que não existe instrução alguma depois do *label*, então não tem um endereço de fato ali, não tem como o *label* apontar para endereço algum porque é o fim da função. Se precisa encerrar a função use o `return`.

Um uso mais real, mas não é um bom exemplo porque tem coisas antigas, ruins e o uso do `goto` é desnecessário ([retirado da documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)):

```
public class GotoTest1 {
    static void Main() {
        int x = 200, y = 4;
        int count = 0;
        string[,] array = new string[x, y];
        // Initialize the array.
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                array[i, j] = (++count).ToString();
        // Read input.
        Console.Write("Enter the number to search for: ");
        // Input a string.
        string myNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        // Search.
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                if (array[i, j].Equals(myNumber)) {
                    goto Found;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"The number {myNumber} was not found.");
        goto Finish;
    Found:
        Console.WriteLine($"The number {myNumber} is found.");
    Finish:
        Console.WriteLine("End of search.");
        // Keep the console open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Sem `goto` e melhorado (dá para melhorar mais):

```
using static System.Console;

public class GotoTest1 {
    static void Main() {
        int x = 200, y = 4;
        var count = 0;
        var array = new string[x, y];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                array[i, j] = (++count).ToString();
        Write("Enter the number to search for: ");
        var myNumber = ReadLine();
        bool found = Search(array, x, y, myNumber);
        if (found) WriteLine($"The number {myNumber} is found.");
        else WriteLine($"The number {myNumber} was not found.");
        WriteLine("End of search.");
    }
    private static bool Search(string[,] array, int x, int y, string myNumber) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) if (array[i, j] == myNumber) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qX9Tva). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lufxd8). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/FillMatrix.cs).

Comment: Uau! Já tinha ouvido falar do goto mas nem imaginava que seria isso neste caso. Me ajudou muito aqui. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @GustavoPinatti agora você pode votar em tudo no site.