# Código para gerar sequência de números aleatórios não funciona

Tags: c, if, random

Desenvolvi um código em C para gerar uma sequência de números aleatórios a serem digitados pelo usuário, porém é a primeira vez que faço um código-fonte do tipo para um trabalho da faculdade, e segundo as pesquisas que fiz consegui montar uma ideia:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  int quant_random; //Quantidade de aleatórios gerados

  inicio:
  printf("Escreva uma quantidade de numeros aleatorios a serem gerados: ");
  scanf("%d", quant_random);
  if (quant_random <= 0 || quant_random > 100)
  {
      printf("\nValor incorreto, digite um numero entre 1 e 100");
      goto inicio; //Estou usando esse goto para levar ele para a frase de novo quando a pessoa digitar um valor incorreto
  }

  else
  {

        srand(100); //Modelo que encontrei em site como base, só não estou entendendo a lógica de como ele funciona
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
        /* gerando valores aleatórios entre zero e 100 */
        printf("\n\n%d ", rand() % 100);
        }

  getch();
  }

    return 0;
}
```

Porém ao executar ele ele pede para entrar como um valor, porém nas duas condições: digitando um código no intervalo de 1 a 100 ou até mesmo fora desse escopo ele não apresenta nenhum retorno. Porque como coloquei no if se for menor ou igual a 0 ou maior que 100 ele deveria voltar pra mensagem inicial através do goto. Alguém consegue entender a lógica para acertar ele?

O enunciado diz que o número digitado pelo usuário é a quantidade a ser números aleatórios a serem gerados.[image: Deveria entrar no if e o loop levar ele para a primeira fase novamente]

Comment: Faltou o `&` em `scanf("%d", quant_random);`. Note que como está partindo de uma semente fixa (`srand(100);`) a sequencia de números pseudo-aleatórios gerada será sempre a mesma todas as vezes que rodar o programa. Evite o uso de goto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h> //para gerar numeros aleatorios
int main()
{
  int i;
  int quant_random; //Quantidade de aleatórios gerados

  srand(time(0)); //de 100 para time(0)

  printf("Escreva uma quantidade de numeros aleatorios a serem gerados: ");
  scanf("%d", &quant_random);
  while(quant_random <= 0 || quant_random > 100)
  {
    printf("\nValor incorreto, digite um numero entre 1 e 100");
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < quant_random; i++){
        /* gerando valores aleatórios entre zero e 100 */
        printf("\n\n%d ", rand() % 100);   
  }

    return 0;
}
```

**Explicação:**

Primeiro eu retirei o [`goto`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20874/195519).

> A razão pela qual as pessoas dizem para evitar o goto é a legibilidade. Seria para facilitar o entendimento do código, para o programador não se perder no que o código faz. O goto em si não causa problema algum.

> O goto ainda existe porque ele ainda é útil. Ele existe porque a maioria dos criadores de linguagens são pragmáticos.

Em seguida alterei o seu `srand()`, não vou explicar detalhadamente aqui, [pois tem essa explicação muito boa](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rand-and-srand-in-ccpp/)

Mas vou dar uma resumida, se você não colocar o `srand()` ele sempre gerara a mesma sequencia de numeros, essa sequencia muda de computador para computador, mas não importe quantas vezes você rode será o mesmo.

Com um valor fixo como o `100` ele ira utilizar o `100` como uma `seed`(semente), e ira gerar o mesmo numero SEMPRE, agora com o `time(0)` ele basicamente pega o número de segundos atual de acordo com a [marca temporal `UNIX`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix#Marca_temporal_UNIX).

Assim fazendo com que o código gere numeros pseudo aleatorios.

O `while` é para verificar se o número digitado está entre `1-100` e o `for` para mostrar a quantidade desejada de números aleatorios.

[Coloquei no Repl.it para referencia futura](https://repl.it/@Cdigodede/SquigglyCrookedSpools#main.c)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, li o artigo do geeks for geeks e seguindo sua explicação também consegui entender a lógica por trás e resolvi o problema, refiz o código da sua forma e funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Seu programa só mostrara 5 números, pois você mandou o laço repetir 5 vezes. Deveria passar

```cpp
 for (i = 0; i <= quant_random; i++);
```

Aqui a quantidade de vezes que o laço repetirá será a definida em `quant_random`