# Por que usar GOTO em Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, goto

Em um código que eu peguei em Delphi 7 vi a utilização de `goto` que poderia ser substituído por uma `procedure` e teria o mesmo efeito.

Existe alguma situação em que uma `procedure` não iria ter o mesmo efeito?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20660/por-que-o-uso-de-goto-%c3%a9-considerado-ruim  acho que essa pergunta cobre vários pontos da pergunta

Comment: Veio do Pascal , caiu em desuso com a noção de programação estruturada , não use , não faz sentido    ...   https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_estruturada

Comment: Outro dia precisei fazer uma "gambiarra" em Oracle PLSQL , precisei "pular" uma Procedure devido a um erro não tratado , usei o goto da linguagem , mas foi uma exceção da exceção ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não temos como avaliar este caso específico porque não o vimos. Mas se nesse caso realmente é tão fácil sair de um `goto` para uma `procedure` sem prejudicar em nada, não tem porque usá-lo.

O `goto` é útil quando torna o código mais fácil e legível. Em alguns raros casos pode melhorar a performance, mas isso quase sempre não dá certo.

`procedure` e `goto` não tem o mesmo efeito. O primeiro vai para outro ponto e depois volta para onde estava. O segundo vai para outro ponto e não volta a não se que o programador faça manualmente, e só neste caso específico que teria o mesmo efeito, mas em conjunto e não de forma pura.

O primeiro pode ter um custo de processamento maior se tiver parâmetros e não houver otimização (linearização), então em outro aspecto pode não ser o mesmo efeito.

Mas se for feito de forma que dê o mesmo efeito então só muda a legibilidade do código. Mas também não muda tanto quanto as pessoas acham em boa parte dos casos.

[Mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -4):

Em outros tempos, no inicio do Pascal, quando não era Orientado a Objeto e não tinha recursos para ir de um método para outro a única alternativa era usar o GOTO já que o código era executado de cima para baixo sem meios de recursividade. Depois dessa implementação GOTO caiu em desuso já que os métodos são mais otimizados para esse fim.

Comment: O que orientação a objeto tem a ver com isso? O que recursividade tem a ver com isso? O que Pascal tem a ver com isso? Delphi é outra linguagem, é pior que falar que C e C++ são a mesma coisa. Pascal sempre teve procedure, sempre teve como ir de uma procedure ou função para outra. Que otimização? Consome mais recursos.

Comment: `"Depois dessa implementação GOTO caiu em desuso"` o GOTO nunca entrou em desuso. Ele tem seus usos particulares, ainda existe, e não é para fazer recursividade (pelo menos não deve ser utilizado para isso).