# Como executar um callback no final de uma promise $http, que funcione em caso de sucesso ou não?

Tags: angularjs, promises

No Angular, estou executando uma chamada `HTTP` através do `$http.get` e, quando essa requisição termina, eu mudo o valor de uma variável através do callback no `then`:

```
$scope.carregando = true;

$http.get('/users/list').then(function (response) {
     $scope.carregando = false;
});
```

Porém, caso haja uma falha nessa requisição, o valor de `$scope.carregando` não é alterado.

Sei que é possível passar um segundo parâmetro para tratar de falhas, assim:

```
$http.get('/users/list').then(function (response) {
     $scope.carregando = false;
}, function () {
     $scope.carregando = false;
});
```

Porém eu não acho que seja uma boa ideia sair repetindo código assim toda vez que eu precisar de executar algo tanto em caso de sucesso como em caso de falhas.

Existe algum método na promise do Angular que executa um callback quando a requisição é terminada, independente de haver falhas (erro 500 e afins) ou não?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe sim, o `finally` é executado independente do sucesso/falha da requisição desta forma não é necessário repetir código:

```
$http.get('/users/list').then(function (response) {
   // código para tratamento do sucesso da requisição
 }, function () {
   // código para tratamento do erro da requisição
 }).finally(function() {
   $scope.carregando = false;
 });
```

Comment: legal é ver que tudo isso se parece com [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16065/como-e-quando-usar-o-finally-ap%C3%B3s-um-try).