# Gerenciamento e liberação de memória

Tags: c#, .net, gerenciamento-de-memória, dispose

1) Quando eu crio um objeto, no qual dentro tem *arrays* e variáveis grandes, definindo-as como `null`, ajudará na redução? Dentro de um método `Dispose()` - sendo que antes estavam com algum valor.

2) Quando eu chamo um `Dispose()`, tanto pelo bloco `using` ou manualmente, os eventos ainda irão disparar? Ainda terão estes registros?

3) Mesmo após um `Dispose()`, ainda existe o objeto? Pois pelo que parece, ele não é apagado, então o `Dispose()` seria apenas para liberar recursos enquanto o `Finalize()` não chama?

- Quais dicas poderiam me dar para melhorar e otimizar neste quesito de liberação de memória?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Quando eu crio um objeto, no qual dentro tem *arrays* e variáveis grandes, definindo-as como `null`, ajudará na redução? Dentro de um método `Dispose()` - sendo que antes estavam com algum valor.

Ajuda mais ou menos, mas nunca deveria se preocupar em anular uma variável. Isso não garante liberação, muito menos quando ocorrerá. Se pode ficar fazendo este tipo de coisa provavelmente tem algum problema de *design*.

> 2. Quando eu chamo um `Dispose()`, tanto pelo bloco `using` ou manualmente, os eventos ainda irão disparar? Ainda terão estes registros?

Que eventos? Chama como? Que registros?

Chamar [`Dispose()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) manualmente é um erro em grande partes das vezes.

Se não liberar eventos manualmente eles vazarão na memória.

> 3. Mesmo após um `Dispose()`, ainda existe o objeto? pois pelo que parece, ele não é apagado, então o `Dispose()` seria apenas para liberar recursos enquanto o `Finalize()` não chama?

Sim, o objeto ainda existe até o *garbage collector* reclamá-lo. O `Dispose()` libera recursos externos, em geral fecha um arquivo ou algo assim. Idealmente o `Finalize()` nunca deveria ser chamado na aplicação. E chamar manualmente eu diria que é sempre um erro.

Já respondi muito sobre isso:

- [Método Dispose()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173210/101)
- [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)
- [Quando devo usar GC.SuppressFinalize()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102609/101)
- [Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101)
- [Como identificar e evitar memory leak no .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186644/101)
- [Como e quando usar o Finally após um Try?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16065/101)

Answer (score 2):

Como você disse, o bloco using é essencial, sempre que posso utilizo o mesmo, pois ele fecha as conexões e dá dispose automático nos objetos ao final da cláusula.

Quando você chama o Dispose() você está "avisando" ao Garbage Collector que aquele objeto está pronto para liberar memória, mas não é instantâneo.

Recomendo esse artigo/vídeo do André Alves Lima onde ele fala exatamente o contexto da sua pergunta com exemplo prático que ajuda muita gente a compreender como funciona esse fluxo

http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2017/11/22/evitando-memory-leaks-no-net-com-dispose-e-blocos-using/