# Mostrar fotografia de um listbox item dá me erro Out Of Memory

Tags: .net, vb.net, gerenciamento-de-memória

Estou a fazer uma ferramenta que transforma uma foto feita *upload* pelo utilizador em bytes *array* depois compara esses bites com as fotos existentes na base de dados

Consegui fazer o código funcionar mas quando no fim ele detectou alguma igual ou parecida então mostra essa do utilizado no `picturebox1` e a encontrada na base de dados que neste caso e inserida em uma `listbox` quando o programa faz *load*.

Quando termina a operação depois de encontrar um *match* ele dá me erro.

O meu erro é:

> Out Of Memory esta na função timer1

O meu código é:

```
Public Class Form3
Dim totalbytes As Integer


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using fo As New OpenFileDialog
        If fo.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim fs As New IO.FileStream(fo.FileName, IO.FileMode.Open)
            Dim br As New IO.BinaryReader(fs)
            Dim byteArea As Byte()
            byteArea = br.ReadBytes(CInt(fs.Length))
            totalbytes = fs.Length
            br.Close()
            'just to show the sample without a fileread error
            'be aware not to use a dispose or using here
            'it gives a GDI+ error as the stream (not the name) is reused.
            Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(byteArea)
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim byteArea As Byte()
    Using msX As New IO.MemoryStream
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(msX, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        byteArea = msX.ToArray()
    End Using
    Using ms2 As New IO.MemoryStream(byteArea)
        Me.PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms2)
    End Using
    Me.PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim finfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\flora")
    For Each fi In finfo.GetFiles
        ListBox1.Items.Add(fi.FullName)
    Next
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1


    ''PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
    Dim ffs As New IO.FileStream(ListBox1.SelectedItem, IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim bbr As New IO.BinaryReader(ffs)
    Dim byteArea As Byte()
    byteArea = bbr.ReadBytes(CInt(ffs.Length))
    If ffs.Length = totalbytes Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        Dim pict2 As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(pict2)

        MsgBox("Resultados Encontrado " + ListBox1.SelectedItem)

    End If

    ''MessageBox.Show(fs.Length)
    bbr.Close()
    'just to show the sample without a fileread error
    'be aware not to use a dispose or using here
    'it gives a GDI+ error as the stream (not the name) is reused.
    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(byteArea)
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

    ''MessageBox.Show(ms.ReadByte)

    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código não está liberando o `fs`, nem o `ms`, embora este último não sei se poderia. Não há garantia que o `br` será liberado assim. Tem outras variáveis que seguram objetos mais que o necessário. E pelo que dá para ver no código pode ter outros problemas em outros pontos.

Se sabe usar o [`Using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259882/101), conforme mostrado no código, faça uso dele para resolver estes problemas. Se o problema persistir tem problemas em outras partes.